# How can I pretty-print JSON in a shell script?

Tags: json, unix, command-line, format, pretty-print

Is there a (Unix) shell script to format JSON in human-readable form?

Basically, I want it to transform the following:

```json
{ "foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" }
```

... into something like this:

```json
{
    "foo": "lorem",
    "bar": "ipsum"
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12892039/998291

Comment: I rolled my own a short while back: https://github.com/exhuma/braindump/tree/master/jsonformat The code is very simple, using python's own `json` library, but I added pygments as well to get syntax highlighting.

Comment: Stumbled on to this but then found [Json Pretty](https://github.com/nicksieger/jsonpretty) and I quite like it. Typekit uses it in their API examples, so there's some klout behind it ^^

Comment: If you don't mind copying pasting, there's also some simple tools online like http://www.jsonprettyprint.net where you can quickly pretty print your raw JSON.

Comment: Just a little cool tidbit that might be super obvious, but for anyone trying to pretty print a file containing JSON this works `echo "$(cat nameOfYourFile.js)" | python -m json.tool`

Comment: Be warned: *python -m json.tool* does not always produce valid JSON. (Hint: 1e1000)

Comment: Is the json only one level deep? This cuts out regex based solutions in case of negative response.

Comment: Anyone have a convenient way to pretty-print a JSON file in-place?

Comment: @LarsH here is interactive JSON viewer https://github.com/antonmedv/fx

Comment: Too many (identical) answers, it is hard to find a listing of possible solutions. [I've made a benchmark to try and summarise those](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61119751/6320039). I hope this won't be yet another useless answer!

Comment: If you want to format your json as a table, you can use jtab, a tool written in rust that allows you to do that: https://github.com/wlezzar/jtab

Comment: Also don't include `-D`

Comment: use [smart json](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/formatter/json) which format json/json5 to compact json format

Answer (score 5131):

With Python 2.6+ or 3 you can use the [json.tool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json.tool) module:

```sh
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | python -m json.tool
```

or, if the JSON is in a file, you can do:

```sh
python -m json.tool my_json.json
```

if the JSON is from an internet source such as an API, you can use

```sh
curl http://my_url/ | python -m json.tool
```

For convenience in all of these cases you can make an alias:

```sh
alias prettyjson='python -m json.tool'
```

---

For even more convenience with a bit more typing to get it ready:

```sh
prettyjson_s() {
    echo "$1" | python -m json.tool
}

prettyjson_f() {
    python -m json.tool "$1"
}

prettyjson_w() {
    curl "$1" | python -m json.tool
}
```

for all the above cases. You can put this in `.bashrc` and it will be available every time in shell. Invoke it like `prettyjson_s '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}'`.

Note that as [@pnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5018816/pnd) pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-in-a-shell-script#comment58654798_1920585) below, in Python 3.5+ the JSON object is no longer sorted by default. To sort, add the [`--sort-keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#cmdoption-json.tool-sort-keys) flag to the end. I.e. `... | python -m json.tool --sort-keys`.

Another useful option might be [`--no-ensure-ascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#cmdoption-json.tool-no-ensure-ascii) which disables escaping of non-ASCII characters (new in version 3.9).

Comment: With other versions of Python you can install simplejson and use python -msimplejson.tool

Comment: You could pipe that onto `pygmentize -l javascript` to get syntax colored output in your command line. **Edit**: If you have pygments installed that is.

Comment: alias ppj='python -mjson.tool'; echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | ppj

Comment: A great answer, only caution I have with it is it *does* sort the keys on output - which you might need to be aware of.

Comment: In myy .vimrc "nnoremap <f5> :%!python -m json.tool<CR>:w<CR>"

Comment: This seems to escape Unicode characters into \uXXXX, which might be a disadvantage.

Comment: This is tip is super handy when viewing Riak or (other JSON-capable servers) output!  e.g. curl http://blah.com:8089 | python -mjson.tool You absolutely don't need to install or configiure anything except python, which is usually there already.

Comment: hey can anyone help with adding this as a external command in gedit? Edit: got it; Tools -> Manage External Toosl -> new (+) -> add "python -mjson.tool " -> Select Input = Current Document, Output = Replace Current Document. Cheers!

Comment: Anyone got the same for XML?

Comment: @MikeWeller http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090869/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-the-command-line

Comment: and add syntax highlighting by piping the output into 'colout -t json'. Requires 'pip install colout' first.

Comment: @user1071136 To keep the Unicode characters in the output it is necessary to make your own script. import sys
import json

j = json.load(sys.stdin)
json.dump(j, sys.stdout,
    ensure_ascii=False,
    sort_keys=True,
    indent=4,
    separators=(',', ': '))

Comment: It doesn't accept top level arrays, so not all json sadly.

Comment: @ShrikantSharat: since version 1.5 Pygments support `json` type as well.

Comment: I've created an alias: `alias pretty='python -mjson.tool | pygmentize -l json` so that I can just run: `command params | pretty`. Hope this helps. PS: Should anyone manages to extend this to a) remove the curl-output I'm seeing every time and/or b) NOT sort the json keys; please do let me know, I will be highly thankful.

Comment: And if the JSON is in a file:
`$ cat file.json | python -m json.tool`

Comment: Another problem with *python -m json.tool* as a JSON pretty-printer is that it does not always print valid JSON values.  E.g. 1e1000 is converted to Infinity.

Comment: python does not support non-ascii

Comment: Changed in Python 3.5: Output now same order as Input. Use `--sort-keys` to sort keys alphabetically. In response to comment by @ChrisNash.

Comment: If you're on macOS and you have some json on the clipboard that you want formatted `pbpaste | python -m json.tool | pbcopy`.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for sharing this. Also, in case you have passed in the "-i" option to cURL, it won't be able to pretty print the json as you have now got HTTP headers as well.

Comment: What if I want to `cat` it using `python -m json.tool /path.json`?

Comment: Is there a way to format the brackets in a better way? (Use same column for the left bracket and the corresponding right bracket)

Comment: @ClintEastwood - the curl -s option will supress the output e.g. `curl -s http://my_url/ | python -m json.tool` Should just print the JSON.

Comment: This effectively just answers how to do it in Python, or on the web. The letter of the question seems to be satisfied, but I don't think the spirit of it has been at all. 3,551 upvotes seems like a gross overreaction.

Comment: which module is required to be installed? I get: /usr/bin/python: `No module named json.module`

Comment: @ClintEastwood To suppress the progress report / bar of `curl`, just pass the silent flag: `curl -s`

Comment: is this the highest voted unaccepted answer of all time

Comment: The technique from this answer, for all `.json` files in your current directory: `for file in *.json; do python -m json.tool $file > ${file/.json/.pretty.json}; done`

Comment: `json.tool` does not work well for large files. There is a `fp.read()` in there somewhere reading the entire JSON file.

Comment: This does not work if your json contains unicode. Pretty sad that this is the most up voted answer.

Comment: I just want to add that to anyone who cannot print no ascii values with this approach that as of python >=3.9 you can do: $ python -m json.tool --no-ensure-ascii to print them.

Comment: Since python 3 is default for Ubuntu, the new alias is: `alias pretty='python3 -mjson.tool | pygmentize -l json'`

Comment: @user1071136 run it with [`--no-ensure-ascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#cmdoption-json.tool-no-ensure-ascii)

Comment: How can I use this to write to the file in place?

Answer (score 1541):

You can use: [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/)

It's very simple to use and it works great! It can handle very large JSON structures, including streams.  You can find
their tutorials [here](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/tutorial/).

Usage examples:

```
$ jq --color-output . file1.json file1.json | less -R

$ command_with_json_output | jq .

$ jq # stdin/"interactive" mode, just enter some JSON

$ jq <<< '{ "foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" }'
{
  "bar": "ipsum",
  "foo": "lorem"
}
```

Or use `jq` with identity filter:

```
$ jq '.foo' <<< '{ "foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" }'
"lorem"
```

Comment: There is also a `--sort-keys` option, which is helpful in some cases.

Comment: jq is a great tool, which I discovered through this answer. Be aware however that it requires whole objects to work on. It won't start outputting results until it has read in the whole input object.

Comment: Working with curl: `curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=5' | jq '.'`

Comment: "jq ." is great as a pretty-printer, but it comes with a caveat: jq (up to and including jq version 1.5) will alter the values of very large and very small numbers because it parses numeric values as IEEE 754 64-bit values.   To check whether your favorite pretty-printer has the same issue, try this value: 1e1000.  Note that *python -mjson.tool* fails this test badly in that it produces Infinity, which is not even JSON.

Comment: As a note, you can redirect the formatted result to a file:
`echo '{ "foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" }' | jq . > myfile`.

Comment: @Meekohi the alternative is "unnecessary use of echo". Super happy to have found the `<<<` operator – exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Here's a nice runthru of `jq`'s features, including a section on pretty-printing: https://shapeshed.com/jq-json/#how-to-pretty-print-json. One way to write your ugly file to a pretty one: `cat ugly.json | jq '.' | cat > pretty.json`

Comment: Typing `cat | jq .` and then pasting used to work. No longer, it seems... jq just exits for some reason. Now I use my paste-from-clipboard alias: `clipread | jq`. The alias is `alias clipread='xclip -out -selection clipboard'` (add this to your `~/.bashrc` or zshrc or whatever-rc, and choose an alias name that you like).

Comment: Reading from a file `jq . <<< cat filename.json`

Comment: `jq`  is the best because it prints in colors!

Comment: @Luc . Try `cat - | jq .` with pasted text. Good luck to all.

Comment: `jq -C ` to include colors.  If you piping the output to `less`, then `export LESS="-R"` and then use `jq -C ... | less`.  Without `-C`, `jq` suppresses colors when the output is not directed to a terminal, as in `| command` or `> file`.

Comment: jq has the irritating property that it will silently loose precision on numbers. E.g. if your input has `"foo": 16962331779841739123` then `jq '.'` will silently round the number to `"foo": 16962331779841739000`. If I'm only looking for a pretty-printer, then I'd chose one that's not lossy.

Comment: +1 unlike the python solution, jq also handles some improperly formatted data (e.g. Ubiquiti's NVR backup files) like this: `echo '{"foo":0}{"bar":1}' | jq` where python chokes on the missing comma and gives no formatted output.

Comment: `echo '{"value": 1e1000}' | fx .value`

Comment: Why on earth is this answer with more than 1000 upvotes hidden on page 2? `jq` is by far one of the best tools for the job. Stack Overflow needs to improve its answer sorting algorithm.

Comment: On macOS: `brew install jq`

Comment: Inspired by @HoverRuan and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69821438/1705829), remove `.`: `curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=5' | jq`

Comment: I also like `pbpaste | jq`

Answer (score 412):

I use the "space" argument of [`JSON.stringify`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.12.3) to pretty-print JSON in JavaScript.

Examples:

```js
// Indent with 4 spaces
JSON.stringify({"foo":"lorem","bar":"ipsum"}, null, 4);

// Indent with tabs
JSON.stringify({"foo":"lorem","bar":"ipsum"}, null, '\t');
```

From the Unix command-line with Node.js, specifying JSON on the command line:

```
$ node -e "console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.argv[1]), null, '\t'));" \
  '{"foo":"lorem","bar":"ipsum"}'
```

Returns:

```
{
    "foo": "lorem",
    "bar": "ipsum"
}
```

From the Unix command-line with Node.js, specifying a filename that contains JSON, and using an indent of four spaces:

```
$ node -e "console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(require('fs') \
      .readFileSync(process.argv[1])), null, 4));"  filename.json
```

Using a pipe:

```
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | node -e \
"\
 s=process.openStdin();\
 d=[];\
 s.on('data',function(c){\
   d.push(c);\
 });\
 s.on('end',function(){\
   console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(d.join('')),null,2));\
 });\
"
```

Comment: For debugging objects in Node.js, you should really use sys.inspect() instead of JSON.stringify(). Here's why: http://markhansen.co.nz/inspecting-with-json-stringify/

Comment: Downvoted. The OP is about a "*nix command-line script" and this answer is a different context.

Comment: @danorton: JS can be used from the commandline via node.js and other similar solutions.

Comment: Use `node -e "console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.argv[1]), null, '\t'));"` on the Unix command-line (with nodejs)

Comment: node -e 'var f = require("./package.json"); console.log(f.name);' Even shorter :D :D :D

Comment: No need for the console: `node -p "JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.argv[1]), null, '\t');"` also outputs the result to STDOUT.

Comment: JSON.stringify i always use

Comment: It sucks that the script is different for a filename vs. stdin

Comment: @LukaszWiktor it doesn't have to be if your *nix supports `/dev/stdin`!

Comment: Why don't you use `require('util').inspect(JSON.parse(obj))`? It provides pretty printing, colors and [a bunch of other features](https://dev.to/siddharthshyniben/the-node-js-util-module-3nbd#:~:text=now%2C%20you%20may%20think%20it%20is%20just%20an%20equivalent%20of%20console.log(json.stringify(obj))%2C%20but%20there%20is%20a%20lot%20more%20functionality%20available%20using%20the%20options%20object.%20some%20of%20the%20more%20useful%20options%20are%3A)

Comment: the article @GurpartapSingh linked is not available anymore. for anyone who wanted to read it, [here's the most recent capture](https://web.archive.org/web/20130208101422/http://markhansen.co.nz/inspecting-with-json-stringify) from the wayback machine

Comment: @GurpartapSingh your link is dead. That's why I don't like external links.

Answer (score 358):

I wrote a tool that has one of the best "smart whitespace" formatters available. It produces more readable and less verbose output than most of the other options here.

[underscore-cli](http://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli)

This is what "smart whitespace" looks like:

[image]

I may be a bit biased, but it's an awesome tool for printing and manipulating JSON data from the command-line. It's super-friendly to use and has extensive command-line help/documentation. It's a Swiss Army knife that I use for 1001 different small tasks that would be surprisingly annoying to do any other way.

Latest use-case: Chrome, Dev console, Network tab, export all as HAR file, "cat site.har | underscore select '.url' --outfmt text | grep mydomain"; now I have a chronologically ordered list of all URL fetches made during the loading of my company's site.

Pretty printing is easy:

```bash
underscore -i data.json print
```

Same thing:

```bash
cat data.json | underscore print
```

Same thing, more explicit:

```bash
cat data.json | underscore print --outfmt pretty
```

This tool is my current passion project, so if you have any feature requests, there is a good chance I'll address them.

Comment: I also updated my ~/.bash_profile to have the following line:
alias underscor='underscore print --outfmt pretty'

now I can just do curl http://example.com/result.json | underscor

and still use underscore for other formatting

Comment: Thanks Dave! Tool is good! alias pretty-json="underrsore pretty" and curl output pleasing an eye

Comment: Great formatting tool, just one note: forwarding output to a file (either with _-o_ option or with _>_ ) works only with _underscore print_. _underscore pretty_ saves a file with color formatting signs being inserted, smth like: `[32m`, `[33m`, `[39m` along with some non-printable before each of them, which makes JSON not valid. However, _underscore print_ alone doesn't add anything to a file and does its formatting job perfectly.

Comment: I love `jq` but this worked great for my "JSON" that didn't have double quoted keys.

Comment: @DaveDopson thanks for the great tool!!  Gonna try using it alongside http://jsonselect.org/#tryit ...

Comment: Also, using `npm` (use creationix/nvm :) ) to install, because it should be global:

    npm install -g underscore-cli


... then in `.bash_profile`:

    alias json='underscore print --color' 

... and use like:

    cat some.json | json

Underscore-CLI is really great and easy to integrate into your development environment.

Answer (score 185):

I usually just do:

```
echo '{"test":1,"test2":2}' | python -mjson.tool
```

And to retrieve select data (in this case, "test"'s value):

```bash
echo '{"test":1,"test2":2}' | python -c 'import sys,json;data=json.loads(sys.stdin.read()); print data["test"]'
```

If the JSON data is in a file:

```
python -mjson.tool filename.json
```

If you want to do it all in one go with `curl` on the command line using an authentication token:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Token wef4fwef54te4t5teerdfgghrtgdg53" http://testsite/api/ | python -mjson.tool
```

Comment: if the json is supposed to come directly froma http api this is also a nice tool implemented in python: https://github.com/jkbr/httpie

Comment: If you have node installed (and don't mind the YAML style output) there's also this package: http://rafeca.com/prettyjson/ so you can end a curl with    `| prettyjson`

Comment: As noted above, one of the problems with *python -mjson.tool* as a JSON pretty-printer is that it does not always emit JSON.  E.g. 1e1000 becomes Infinity (whether using python 2.x or 3.x).  'jq .' always produces JSON, but it does not guarantee that very large (or very small values) are preserved exactly.

Answer (score 104):

If you use npm and Node.js, you can do `npm install -g json` and then pipe the command through `json`.  Do `json -h` to get all the options. It can also pull out specific fields and colorize the output with `-i`.

```
curl -s http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=node.js | json
```

Answer (score 101):

It is not too simple with a native way with [the jq tools](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/).

For example:

```
cat xxx | jq .
```

Comment: WARNING: jq encodes numbers as IEEE 754 64-bit floats, and thus their representation is likely to change. The precision of very small and very large numbers is likely to be lost.  To check whether your favorite pretty-printer has the same issue, try this value: 1e1000.

Comment: or simply: `jq .  file.json` ; but also `cat file.json | jq` (without the filter `.`) also works. (on ubuntu/linux; ymmv across platforms)

Comment: Already installed in Ubuntu and colors as well. Nice

Answer (score 95):

Thanks to J.F. Sebastian's very helpful pointers, here's a slightly enhanced script I've come up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Convert JSON data to human-readable form.

Usage:
  prettyJSON.py inputFile [outputFile]
"""

import sys
import simplejson as json


def main(args):
    try:
        if args[1] == '-':
            inputFile = sys.stdin
        else:
            inputFile = open(args[1])
        input = json.load(inputFile)
        inputFile.close()
    except IndexError:
        usage()
        return False
    if len(args) < 3:
        print json.dumps(input, sort_keys = False, indent = 4)
    else:
        outputFile = open(args[2], "w")
        json.dump(input, outputFile, sort_keys = False, indent = 4)
        outputFile.close()
    return True


def usage():
    print __doc__


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(not main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: When the values are loaded into the dictionary, the order is lost: normal `dict` objects do not have a defined order. Try `json.dumps(json.loads('{"b": 1, "a": 2}'), sort_keys=False)` and you'll find they're swapped anyway. To fix it, import `OrderedDict` and `load` passing `object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict`.

Comment: You can change the script to read from standard input with this: `inputFile = sys.stdin`. This lets you pipe stuff to the script like so: `curl http://somewhere.com/foo.json | pp_json.py`

Comment: And to avoid sorting with @icktoofay's comment, import OrderedDict like this: `from collections import OrderedDict`.

Comment: Thanks @icktoofay.  This allowed me to create the following vim function:  

`com! FormatJSON %!python -c "from collections import OrderedDict; import sys; import json; j = json.load(sys.stdin, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict); json.dump(j,     sys.stdout, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))"`

Note that the separators must be set as (',', ': ') to avoid trailing whitespace being added: https://bugs.python.org/issue16333

Comment: Great snippet!  I've used `sort_keys = True` instead, because I want to use this to compare json files and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 86):

a simple bash script for pretty json printing

json_pretty.sh

```bash
#/bin/bash

grep -Eo '"[^"]*" *(: *([0-9]*|"[^"]*")[^{}\["]*|,)?|[^"\]\[\}\{]*|\{|\},?|\[|\],?|[0-9 ]*,?' | awk '{if ($0 ~ /^[}\]]/ ) offset-=4; printf "%*c%s\n", offset, " ", $0; if ($0 ~ /^[{\[]/) offset+=4}'
```

Example:

```
cat file.json | json_pretty.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just wrote this script today for personal using and it worked fine in my cases. I made fixes, now it's smaller and without this problem. There is not a goal to support completely format, but i can make other fixes if necessary.

Comment: That is only working answer I found. I have an embedded linux - no rubby, no javascript, no access to internet to download python modules... I have slightly different awk that does not support `%*c` notation so I changed the `printf` to `c=0; while (c++<offset) printf " "; printf $0;`. And my awk has different regex escaping and backslash does not work in `[]`. I changed the regexes to `/^[[{]/` and `/[]}]/`.

Comment: This should be the accepted, as it's full native and don't require third party software...

Comment: @Blag the script looked broken after your editing, please explain or correct it. thanks!

Comment: @EvgenyKarpov nice catch, no need for a full rollback, just the `grep` that was erased by mistake ;)

Comment: This script is pretty fragile and it doesn't support full json syntax. For example it turns `{ "\"" : "quote" }` into `{  "\" " : " }` (on multiple lines).

Comment: This works pretty well with piping. `getMyLogs | grep -Eo ...`

Comment: Thanks dude, I wanted a quick way to format an 8MB one-liner json, in bare simple bash.

Comment: In my case, I also needed to execute `json_pretty.sh`, e.g. `cat file.json | ./json_pretty.sh`

Comment: Best solution if you have a stand-alone script and you don't want to make someone install Homebrew, python, ruby, node.js...

Comment: Really good answer. This is the only method that worked for me to deal with a broken json oneline file. Thanks

Comment: @UrsineRaven feel free to bring your changes to the post if it brings improvements

Comment: @EvgenyKarpov I apparently need 100 reputation to do that, but I also just noticed that I should have changed `[0-9 ]*,?` to `[0-9]+ *,?|,` instead of `[0-9]+ *,?`, so that we don't lose the commas after arrays in objects (i.e. with my above comment, we lose the comma after `]` in `{"a":[1,2],"b":"c"}`). So, I guess I'll just have to delete my comment and repost it with the fix for now.

Comment: I made @ZabojCampula's changes (also necessary for me) and I also made a fix for what @Rotsor mentioned and came up with this: `grep -Eo '"([^"\]*(\\")*(\\[^"])*)*" *(: *([0-9]*|"([^"\]*(\\")*(\\[^"])*)*")[^{}\["]*|,)?|[^"\]\[\}\{]*|\{|\},?|\[|\],?|[0-9]+ *,?|,' | awk '{if ($0 ~ /^[]}]/ ) offset-=4; c=0; while (c++<offset) printf " "; printf "%s\n",$0; if ($0 ~ /^[[{]/) offset+=4}'`. To fix the `{ "\"" : "quote" }` test case, I changed the instances of `"[^"]*"` to `"([^"\]*(\\")*(\\[^"])*)*"` and changed `[0-9 ]*,?` to `[0-9]+ *,?|,` at end of grep regex (prevent empty lines from test case)

Comment: I ended up making [a script](https://gist.github.com/UrsineRaven/95061d097de04d9130f470a4c0200a91) (based on the JSON definition on json.org) that should be mostly language complete for JSON and pretty-prints the JSON that is piped into it.

Comment: The great thing about this is that unlike the higher ranking answers, it actually doesn't fail on encountering unprintable characters! Kudos!

Answer (score 77):

With Perl, use the CPAN module `JSON::XS`. It installs a command line tool `json_xs`.

Validate:

```bash
json_xs -t null < myfile.json
```

Prettify the JSON file `src.json` to `pretty.json`:

```bash
< src.json json_xs > pretty.json
```

If you don't have `json_xs`, try `json_pp` . "pp" is for "pure perl" – the tool is implemented in Perl only, without a binding to an external C library (which is what XS stands for, Perl's "Extension System").

Comment: Seems to come standard with Cygwin!

Comment: json_pp can be used in the same way and is most probably readily installed on your system (on Debian it is in the 'perl' package).

Comment: FYI, on my Mac OS X 10.9 system, json_pp is available automatically.

Comment: `-t null` gave me _null: not a valid toformat_...  but leaving it off worked splendidly.  Thanks.

Comment: pp is for pure perl, not pretty print here :) Since json_xs and json_pp can do more than just pretty print and also with -json_opt do other things instead of pretty printing. Although pretty printing is the default behaviour.

Comment: `json_xs` and `json_pp` neither preserve key order nor sort the keys. Pretty-printing the same JSON file twice is likely to produce different results. (Tested with perl-5.26.1-6 and libjson-xs-perl-3.040-1 on Ubuntu 18.04.)

Answer (score 75):

That's how I do it:

```
curl yourUri | json_pp
```

It shortens the code and gets the job done.

Comment: Ubuntu server: If you have production machines with very restricted installations, this might be the best choice as it is installed by default under a specific name.  Python is often installed in different ways (eg python3, python or not at all) depending on the version.

Comment: works for mac :)

Comment: Works for both MacOS and Linux (Debian) by default. I'd recommend this answer

Answer (score 74):

On *nix, reading from stdin and writing to stdout works better:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Convert JSON data to human-readable form.

(Reads from stdin and writes to stdout)
"""

import sys
try:
    import simplejson as json
except:
    import json

print json.dumps(json.loads(sys.stdin.read()), indent=4)
sys.exit(0)
```

Put this in a file (I named mine "prettyJSON" after [AnC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83069/anc)'s answer) in your PATH and `chmod +x` it, and you're good to go.

Comment: Indeed, using stdin/stdout is much more flexible and simple. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: For programs that expect a named file, use /dev/stdin, ditto for out and err.

Comment: FYI [`fileinput.input()`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) reads from stdin if there are no files given at a command-line. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-to-pretty-print-json-script/352160#352160)

Comment: fileinput.input() can't deal well with files with no newline at the end, last time I checked.

Comment: he askes in shell script, not python other language. With JQ can do it perfectly.

Answer (score 68):

```bash
$ echo '{ "foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" }' \
> | python -c'import fileinput, json;
> print(json.dumps(json.loads("".join(fileinput.input())),
>                  sort_keys=True, indent=4))'
{
    "bar": "ipsum",
    "foo": "lorem"
}
```

NOTE: It is not *the* way to do it.

The same in Perl:

```
$ cat json.txt \
> | perl -0007 -MJSON -nE'say to_json(from_json($_, {allow_nonref=>1}), 
>                                     {pretty=>1})'
{
   "bar" : "ipsum",
   "foo" : "lorem"
}
```

Note 2:
If you run

```bash
echo '{ "Düsseldorf": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" }' \
| python -c'import fileinput, json;
print(json.dumps(json.loads("".join(fileinput.input())),
                 sort_keys=True, indent=4))'
```

the nicely readable word becomes \u encoded

```
{
    "D\u00fcsseldorf": "lorem", 
    "bar": "ipsum"
}
```

If the remainder of your pipeline will gracefully handle unicode and you'd like your JSON to also be human-friendly, simply [use](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) `ensure_ascii=False`

```bash
echo '{ "Düsseldorf": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" }' \
| python -c'import fileinput, json;
print json.dumps(json.loads("".join(fileinput.input())),
                 sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)'
```

and you'll get:

```
{
    "Düsseldorf": "lorem", 
    "bar": "ipsum"
}
```

What's more, you could make this a function in shell Using python script:

```bash
json_format(){
    python3 -c'import fileinput, json; \
        print(json.dumps(json.loads("".join(fileinput.input())), \
                sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))'
}
```

then you can use `cat json.txt | json_format`

Comment: actually I do the same but with javascript itself :)

Comment: In the version of the JSON module I have, `to_json` doesn't seem to accept options. But this works:
`perl -MJSON -nE 'say JSON->new->pretty->encode(from_json $_)' text.json`

Comment: The Python example could be simplified. It's much easier to pipe JSON output straight into `python -m json.tool`.

Comment: @Dan: yes. And there are several answers that show `json.tool` code examples. 1. this version allows you to change some parameters e.g., `indent` 2.  At the time of the posting (2008) Python 2.4 was still used [that doesn't support `-mjson.tool`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json#comment7007134_1920585)

Comment: @dwlz command-line version with unicode characters (requires python3.9+): python -m json.tool --no-ensure-ascii in.json out.json

Comment: ```json_format(){
    python3 -c'import fileinput, json; \
        print(json.dumps(json.loads("".join(fileinput.input())), \
                sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))'
}``` 
make this a function,  `cat example.json | json_format`

Answer (score 68):

The JSON Ruby Gem is bundled with a shell script to prettify JSON:

```
sudo gem install json
echo '{ "foo": "bar" }' | prettify_json.rb
```

Script download:  [gist.github.com/3738968](http://gist.github.com/3738968)

Comment: Note that this solution decode the unicode "\uxxxx" escape sequences, unlike the Python one with `json.tool`. However, it also seems to have nesting depth limitations (`nesting of 20 is too deep (JSON::NestingError)`).

Comment: on Ubuntu you can do: ``sudo apt-get install ruby-json-pure`` instead of ``gem install``

Comment: ```eric-mbp:~ ericstob$ sudo gem install json
Password:
Fetching: json-1.7.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed json-1.7.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for json-1.7.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for json-1.7.3...
eric-mbp:~ ericstob$ prettify_json.rb
-bash: prettify_json.rb: command not found

Comment: maybe you could post the contents of your `prettify_json.rb`?

Comment: You can download the script, move it to your `~/bin` folder (make sure it's in your PATH) rename `prettify_json.rb` to `ppj` and run `chmod +x ppj`. Now you can do something like `curl www.jsonsring.com/something.json | ppj`

Comment: `prettify_json.rb` ships with Ruby 1.9 and later

Answer (score 60):

**UPDATE** I'm using `jq` now as suggested in another answer. It's extremely powerful at filtering JSON, but, at its most basic, also an awesome way to pretty print JSON for viewing.

[jsonpp](https://github.com/jmhodges/jsonpp) is a very nice command line JSON pretty printer.

From the README:

> Pretty print web service responses like so:
>
> ```bash
> curl -s -L http://<!---->t.co/tYTq5Pu | jsonpp
> ```
>
> and make beautiful the files running around on your disk:
>
> ```bash
> jsonpp data/long_malformed.json
> ```

If you're on Mac OS X, you can `brew install jsonpp`. If not, you can simply copy the binary to somewhere in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I tried jsonpp (used in the past successful) against a huge file (>60MB). I stopped it after 5min. I piped it into `python -mjson.tool` (from other answer here) and it took 10-20sec...

Comment: 60MB of JSON? Wow! I don't typically deal with files that big but useful to know. Thanks.

Comment: On my ubuntu box I have a `json_pp` - which does format json nicely, although despite the similarity in naming, I believe this to be an entirely different project from the `jsonpp` mentioned here

Answer (score 54):

Try [`pjson`](https://github.com/igorgue/pjson). It has colors!

[image: echo '{"json":"obj"} | pjson]

Install it with `pip`:

`⚡ pip install pjson`

And then pipe any JSON content to `pjson`.

Comment: It requires python-pip
 (sudo apt-get install python-pip)
and then
 (sudo pip install pjson)
The great advantage are colours!

Comment: The disadvantage is it is  not possible to grep coloured output.

Comment: How can I use this tool to read from a file and format it in-place, writing back to the same file?

Answer (score 47):

You only need to use `jq`

If jq is not installed then you need to install jq first:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jq
```

After installing jq then only need to use `jq`:

```bash
echo '{ "foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" }' | jq
```

Output looks like

```
{
  "foo": "lorem",
  "bar": "ipsum"
}
```

Comment: Or `brew install jq` if you're on a mac.

Comment: How can I use jq to read from a file and write to that same file in-place?

Answer (score 44):

Or, with Ruby:

```bash
echo '{ "foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" }' | ruby -r json -e 'jj JSON.parse gets'
```

Comment: That gives me an error.  Do you need some ruby json package installed?

Comment: Yes, you need the JSON Ruby Gem: sudo gem install json

Comment: @MatSchaffer Note that this does not work if you are using JSON to serialize objects with custom `to_json` methods; `Kernel#jj` only pretty-prints arrays and hashes of the same (or numbers/strings/booleans).

Comment: On Windows, try this:

`echo { "foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" } | ruby -r json -e 'jj JSON.parse gets'`

Answer (score 42):

You can use this simple command to achieve the result:

```bash
echo "{ \"foo\": \"lorem\", \"bar\": \"ipsum\" }"|python -m json.tool
```

Comment: Best answer in my opinion. Small and easy to remember and doesn't require installing any non-standard tools.

Comment: python -m json.tool doesn't seem to preserve the order of the JSON object.

Comment: It do sorting in python 2, in 3 it does not sort https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/json/tool.py

Answer (score 41):

I use [jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/) to do exactly what you're describing. Just run:

```
echo $COMPACTED_JSON_TEXT | jshon
```

You can also pass arguments to transform the JSON data.

Comment: Thanks, jshon is a lot faster than using python or ruby for the same task

Comment: @Alexander - How fast a pretty printer do you need? I'm on OSx Lion that comes with Python preinstalled. With python -mjson.tool I can pretty print a 96KB json file in 0.1s - the json output of earthporn that jshon links to is about 24KB and I can pretty print that in 0.08s. How much faster is jshon for you?

Comment: I'm working with 1+GB compressed (who even knows how big uncompressed) JSON data files, so I very much appreciate the suggestion that jshon is faster.

Answer (score 39):

Check out [Jazor](https://github.com/mconigliaro/jazor). It's a simple command line JSON parser written in Ruby.

```
gem install jazor
jazor --help
```

Comment: Is it just me or is this the only suggestion that actually answers the OP's question? I came here looking for a simple command into which I could pipe the output of `curl` and this is the only one that did it for me.

Comment: I like that it has the option to colorize the output. Makes it easier to read.

Comment: ooh I also like the option to pass a url since I am using this to view the output of my REST API

Answer (score 31):

[JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) has an [open-source implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint) that can be used on the command line or included in a Node.js project.

```bash
npm install jsonlint -g
```

and then

```bash
jsonlint -p myfile.json
```

or

```bash
curl -s "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/user.json" | jsonlint | less
```

Comment: I recommend not installing nodejs/npm dependencies globally => I'd use `npx` instead: `curl -s "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/user.json" | npx jsonlint | less` (i.e. no `npm install` necessary)

Answer (score 30):

Simply pipe the output to `jq .`.

Example:

```
twurl -H ads-api.twitter.com '.......' | jq .
```

Comment: Nice answer @Ackshaey Singh and one can re-direct the same to a file easily as well. e.g. `cat <file_name.txt> | jq . > <output_name.txt>`

Comment: `brew install jq` if your are on mac os.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `jq .` for pretty-printing has one **potential** drawback: all extant versions of jq insist on treating JSON numbers as IEEE numbers, so precision is easily lost, e.g. for very large integers.

Comment: @Pramit `cat file |` is invariably a waste of a process; just do `jq . <file_name.txt >output_name.txt` (with literal `<` and `>` characters).

Answer (score 29):

You can simply use standard tools like jq or json_pp.

`echo '{ "foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" }' | json_pp`

or

`echo '{ "foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" }' | jq`

will both prettify output like the following (jq even more colorful):

```
{
  "foo": "lorem",
  "bar": "ipsum"
}
```

The huge advantage of jq is that it can do A LOT more if you'd like to parse and process the json.

Comment: json_pp was on my Mac - but not jq. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidH - does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668134/how-to-install-jq-on-mac-by-command-line

Answer (score 25):

With Perl, if you install [JSON::PP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON-PP/) from CPAN you'll get the [json_pp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?json_pp) command.  Stealing the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-to-pretty-print-json-script/1920585#1920585) from [B Bycroft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233648/b-bycroft) you get:

```
[pdurbin@beamish ~]$ echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | json_pp
{
   "bar" : "ipsum",
   "foo" : "lorem"
}
```

It's worth mentioning that `json_pp` comes pre-installed with Ubuntu 12.04 (at least) and Debian in `/usr/bin/json_pp`

Answer (score 25):

## Pygmentize

I combine Python's json.tool with pygmentize:

```
echo '{"foo": "bar"}' | python -m json.tool | pygmentize -g
```

There are some alternatives to pygmentize which are listed in [my this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501509/2670370).

Here is a live demo:

[image: Demo]

Comment: Sometimes one needs to use `pygmentize -l json` to get colourfication.

Comment: Install with apt package `python-pygments`, i.e. `apt-get install python-pygments`

Answer (score 20):

I recommend using the json_xs command line utility which is included in the JSON::XS perl module. JSON::XS is a Perl module for serializing/deserializing JSON, on a Debian or Ubuntu machine you can install it like this:

```bash
sudo apt-get install libjson-xs-perl
```

It is obviously also available on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emlehmann/JSON-XS-2.3/bin/json_xs).

To use it to format JSON obtained from a URL you can use curl or wget like this:

```bash
$ curl -s http://page.that.serves.json.com/json/ | json_xs
```

or this:

```bash
$ wget -q -O - http://page.that.serves.json.com/json/ | json_xs
```

and to format JSON contained in a file you can do this:

```bash
$ json_xs < file-full-of.json
```

To reformat as [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), which some people consider to be more humanly-readable than JSON:

```bash
$ json_xs -t yaml < file-full-of.json
```

Answer (score 20):

[jj](https://github.com/tidwall/jj) is super-fast, can handle ginormous JSON documents economically, does not mess with valid JSON numbers, and is easy to use, e.g.

```bash
jj -p # for reading from STDIN
```

or

```bash
jj -p -i input.json
```

It is (2018) still quite new so maybe it won’t handle invalid JSON the way you expect, but it is easy to install on major platforms.

Answer (score 17):

Install yajl-tools with the command below:

```bash
sudo apt-get install yajl-tools
```

then,

```bash
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | json_reformat
```

Comment: Awesome. Does not require another language/interpreter and is in the package repo's, no need to brew!

Answer (score 17):

[`bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) is a `cat` clone with syntax highlighting:

Example:

```
echo '{"bignum":1e1000}' | bat -p -l json
```

`-p` will output without headers, and `-l` will explicitly specify the language.

It has colouring and formatting for JSON and does *not* have the problems noted in this comment: *[How can I pretty-print JSON in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-in-a-unix-shell-script#comment52647558_15231463)*

Answer (score 17):

When you have node installed on your system the following works.

```
echo '{"test":1,"test2":2}' | npx json

{
  "test": 1,
  "test2": 2
}
```

Answer (score 16):

1. `brew install jq`
2. `command + | jq`
3. (example: `curl localhost:5000/blocks | jq`)
4. Enjoy!

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Use Ruby in one line:

```
echo '{"test":1,"test2":2}' | ruby -e "require 'json'; puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(STDIN.read))"
```

And you can set an alias for this:

```bash
alias to_j="ruby -e \"require 'json';puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(STDIN.read))\""
```

Then you can use it more conveniently

```
echo '{"test":1,"test2":2}' | to_j

{
  "test": 1,
  "test2": 2
}
```

And if you want display JSON with color, your can install `awesome_print`,

```
gem install awesome_print
```

then

```bash
alias to_j="ruby -e \"require 'json';require 'awesome_print';ap JSON.parse(STDIN.read)\""
```

Try it!

```bash
echo '{"test":1,"test2":2, "arr":["aa","bb","cc"] }' | to_j
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

A one-line solution using Node.js will look like this:

```bash
$ node -e "console.log( JSON.stringify( JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(0) ), 0, 1 ))"
```

For example:

```
$ cat test.json | node -e "console.log( JSON.stringify( JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(0) ), 0, 1 ))"
```

Comment: no output for me with this example even though I voted this up long time ago. Something changed ...

Comment: @MatthisKohli: I just rechecked this on Node V12.x and it is working. There is nothing magic in this code. `fs.readFileSync(0)` reads `stdin` of the current process  and `JSON.stringify` formats the JSON. So, there is very less chance for breaking API change

Answer (score 10):

[`yajl`](http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/) is very nice, in my experience. I use its `json_reformat` command to pretty-print `.json` files in `vim` by putting the following line in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType json setlocal equalprg=json_reformat
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is a Ruby solution that is better than Json's prettify command. The gem `colorful_json` is fairly good.

```
gem install colorful_json
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | cjson
{
  "foo": "lorem",
  "bar": "ipsum"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The PHP version, if you have PHP >= 5.4.

```bash
alias prettify_json=php -E '$o = json_decode($argn); print json_encode($o, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);'
echo '{"a":1,"b":2}' | prettify_json
```

Comment: A one liner : `echo '{"a":1,"b":2}' | php -r 'echo json_encode(json_decode(fgets(STDIN)), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."\n";'`

Comment: Multiline capable: `printf '{\n"a":1,\n"b":2\n}' | php -r 'echo json_encode(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://stdin")), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . PHP_EOL;'`

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR**: for performances, use `jj -p < my.json`.

## Benchmark

I took some solutions here and benchmarked them with the next dummy script:

```sh
function bench {
    time (
      for i in {1..1000}; do
        echo '{ "foo" : { "bar": { "dolorem" : "ipsum", "quia" : { "dolor" : "sit"} } } }' \
        | $@ > /dev/null
      done
    )
}
```

Here's the result on my mac (32 GB, Apple M1 Max, YMMV):

```sh
bench python -m json.tool
# 8.39s user 12.31s system 42% cpu 48.536 total
bench jq
# 13.12s user 1.28s system 87% cpu 16.535 total
bench bat -p -l json # NOTE: only syntax colorisation.
# 1.87s user 1.47s system 66% cpu 5.024 total
bench jj -p
# 1.94s user 2.44s system 57% cpu 7.591 total
bench xidel -s - -e '$json' --printed-json-format=pretty                      
# 4.32s user 1.89s system 76% cpu 8.101 total
```

Thanks @peak and your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48974193/6320039) for this discovery of jj!

Comment: Great, but it would be even nicer if it were a more complex and longer JSON test string.

Comment: @HiltonFernandes feel free to edit :)

Comment: Dear @Ulysse BN, if I do edit it to add more complexity to the JSON string, would you please try to run your benchmark again ? Unfortunately I don't have a mac (8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3, 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5) at hand here.

Comment: @HiltonFernandes me neither anymore! But sure I could install stuff and run the benchmark. I'm on an M1 chip now though, so YMMV...

BTW steps to install and run the benchmark on a mac: (1.) `brew install jq bat tidwall/jj/jj xidel`, (2.) copy and paste the function block, (3.) copy and paste the bench block, (4.) edit this post with your configuration (about my mac).

Also please, no need to be complacent, I get the gist...

Comment: Hello, @Ulysse BN, your idea is great and its implementation is very elegant. Congrats also to your M1 powered Mac. Please consider my suggestion of a benchmark in https://gist.github.com/hgfernan/716f599503c21d56ca141da04349ffa1

Comment: @HiltonFernandes there you go

Comment: Many thanks for accepting my suggestion, @Ulysse BN ! Would you mind if I ask you what have been the changes in your benchmark list ?

Comment: @HiltonFernandes you can see changes via the link below the answer ([edited _some time ago_](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61119751/revisions))

Comment: For everyone reading this; the Xidel version used here (v0.9.8) is NOT the recommended binary to use. Binaries from the development branch are, eventhough they might be considered beta! The latest Xidel dev-build is aprox. 3.5-4.5x faster than v0.9.8 in this particular benchmark.

Comment: @Reino I've finally installed xidel 0.9.9, it has **a lot** of dependencies and is not packaged efficiently (TL;DR: `brew install xidel --head` and feel the svn pain). However I'll have to admit, it is fast (`5s`, beats jj). I'd still not advise it: the installation process is heavy, and the the build is yet to be official...

**DISCLAIMER:** I'll stop editing this post from now on. I've added enough information in the comment for anyone else to do it, so **please do!** I'm not paid more than you to do that.

Comment: Great @UlysseBN ! I was wondering that in your original form, the cost of starting lots of light threads could become stronger than the pretty printing itself. Now that each run do a little more work, the thread startup cost is probably proportionally smaller.

Comment: BTW, sorry to have abused of your time, @UlysseBN. People got very interested in your post.

Comment: There's no need to compile Xidel yourself when there are lots of [pre-compiled binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/Xidel%20development/) available. I'm not a Linux user, but if you're referring to https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/xidel.rb, it's outdated and using the wrong sources. The pre-compiled Linux binaries only rely on OpenSSL afaik.

Answer (score 8):

There is [TidyJSON](http://www.raboof.com/Projects/TidyJson/).

It's C#, so maybe you can get it to compile with [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29), and working on *nix. No guarantees though, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

J.F. Sebastian's solutions didn't work for me in Ubuntu 8.04.
Here is a modified Perl version that works with the older 1.X JSON library:

```bash
perl -0007 -MJSON -ne 'print objToJson(jsonToObj($_, {allow_nonref=>1}), {pretty=>1}), "\n";'
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm using [httpie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie)

```
$ pip install httpie
```

And you can use it like this

```
$ http PUT localhost:8001/api/v1/ports/my 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 93
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 02:46:41 GMT
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: HHVM/3.5.1
      
{
    "data": [], 
    "message": "Failed to manage ports in 'my'. Request body is empty", 
    "success": false
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For Node.js you can also use the "util" module. It uses syntax-highlighting, smart indentation, removes quotes from keys and just makes the output as pretty as it gets.

```bash
cat file.json | node -e "process.stdin.pipe(new require('stream').Writable({write: chunk =>  {console.log(require('util').inspect(JSON.parse(chunk), {depth: null, colors: true}))}}))"
```

Answer (score 6):

The tool `ydump` is a JSON pretty-printer:

```
$ ydump my_data.json
{
  "foo": "lorem",
  "bar": "ipsum"
}
```

Or you can pipe in the JSON:

```
$ echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | ydump
{
  "foo": "lorem",
  "bar": "ipsum"
}
```

This is probably the shortest solution apart from using the `jq` tool.

This tool is part of the `yojson` library for [OCaml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocaml), and is documented [here](https://mjambon.github.io/atdgen-doc/tutorial).

On Debian and derivatives, the package `libyojson-ocaml-dev` contains this tool. Alternatively, `yojson` can be installed via [OPAM](https://opam.ocaml.org/).

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sudo apt-get install edit-json
$ prettify_json myfile.json
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have Node.js installed you can create one on your own with one line of code. Create a file pretty:

> > vim pretty

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.argv[2]), null, 2));
```

Add execute permission:

> > chmod +x pretty
>
> > ./pretty '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}'

Or if your JSON is in a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log(JSON.stringify(require("./" + process.argv[2]), null, 2));
```

> > ./pretty file.json

Comment: process.stdin.resume();

var input = '';

process.stdin.on('data', (data) => {
    input += data;
});

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(input), null, 2));
});

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) to do this.

`npx prettier <JSON file>` should print a prettified version of the JSON in the given file, while `npx prettier --write <JSON file>` will overwrite the given JSON file with prettified JSON.

Comment: this was quite simple & easy to use

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to do it with [Groovy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29) script.

Create a Groovy script, let's say "pretty-print"

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import groovy.json.JsonOutput

System.in.withReader { println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(it.readLine()) }
```

Make script executable:

```bash
chmod +x pretty-print
```

Now from the command line,

```bash
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | ./pretty-print
```

Comment: As much as I love Groovy, it isn't a great fit for little scripts like this due to the overhead of the JVM.  My informal measurements show `jq` approximately 50x faster.

Answer (score 4):

I've came up with this solution: https://calbertts.medium.com/unix-pipelines-with-curl-requests-and-serverless-functions-e21117ae4c65

```
# this in your bash profile
jsonprettify() {
  curl -Ss -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data-binary @- https://jsonprettify.vercel.app/api/server?indent=$@
}
```

```
echo '{"prop": true, "key": [1,2]}' | jsonprettify 4
# {
#     "prop": true,
#     "key": [
#         1,
#         2
#     ]
# }
```

There's no need to install anything, if you have an internet connection and cURL installed, you can use this function.

Are you in another host where you can't install anything, this would be a perfect solution to that issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of [json-liner](https://github.com/wuyongzheng/json-liner). It's a command line tool to turn JSON into a grep friendly format. Give it a try.

```
$ echo '{"a": 1, "b": 2}' | json-liner
/%a 1
/%b 2
$ echo '["foo", "bar", "baz"]' | json-liner
/@0 foo
/@1 bar
/@2 baz
```

Answer (score 3):

With JavaScript/Node.js: take a look at the [vkBeautify.js plugin](http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkbeautify/), which provides pretty printing for both JSON and XML text.

It's written in plain JavaScript, less than 1.5 KB (minified) and very fast.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Groovy one-liner:

```bash
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | groovy -e 'import groovy.json.*; println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(System.in.text)'
```

Answer (score 3):

```bash
gem install jsonpretty
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | jsonpretty
```

This method also ["**Detects HTTP response/headers, prints them untouched, and skips to
the body (for use with `curl -i')**"](https://github.com/nicksieger/jsonpretty).

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/aidanmelen/json_pretty_print

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division

import json
import jsonschema

def _validate(data):
    schema = {"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"}
    try:
        jsonschema.validate(data, schema,
                            format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker())
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as ve:
        sys.stderr.write("Whoops, the data you provided does not seem to be " \
        "valid JSON.\n{}".format(ve))

def pprint(data, python_obj=False, **kwargs):
    _validate(data)
    kwargs["indent"] = kwargs.get("indent", 4)
    pretty_data = json.dumps(data, **kwargs)
    if python_obj:
        print(pretty_data)
    else:
       repls = (("u'",'"'),
                ("'",'"'),
                ("None",'null'),
                ("True",'true'),
                ("False",'false'))
    print(reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), repls, pretty_data))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a third-party tool, you can simply *curl* to [jsonprettyprint.org](https://jsonprettyprint.org). This is for the case where you can't install packages on the machine.

```
curl -XPOST https://jsonprettyprint.org/api -d '{"user" : 1}'
```

Comment: To pipe stdin to this command, do something like this: `echo '{ "foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" }' | curl -XPOST https://jsonprettyprint.org/api -d @-`

Answer (score 1):

My JSON files were not parsed by any of these methods.

My problem was similar to the post *[Is Google data source JSON not valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628505/is-google-data-source-json-not-valid)*.

[The answer to that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628505/is-google-data-source-json-not-valid/628634#628634) helped me find a solution.

It is considered to be invalid JSON without the string keys.

```
{id:'name',label:'Name',type:'string'}
```

must be:

```
{"id": "name", "label": "Name", "type": "string"}
```

This link gives a nice comprehensive comparison of some of the different JSON parsers: http://deron.meranda.us/python/comparing_json_modules/basic

Which led me to http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/. I think this one parser is much more fault tolerant than many others.

Comment: JSON does not allow single quotes as delimiters and a sane JSON parser should reject such input.

Comment: The last two links seem to be broken (*"The server at deron.meranda.us is taking too long to respond"*).

Answer (score 1):

Also be sure to check out [JSONFUI: A command line JSON viewer that supports folding](https://github.com/AdrianSchneider/jsonfui)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel).

> Xidel is a command line tool to download and extract data from HTML/XML pages or JSON-APIs, using CSS, XPath 3.0, XQuery 3.0, JSONiq or pattern templates. It can also create new or transformed XML/HTML/JSON documents.

Xidel pretty-prints by default:

```
$ xidel -se '$json' <<< '{"foo":"lorem","bar":"ipsum"}'
{
  "foo": "lorem",
  "bar": "ipsum"
}
```

or:

```
$ echo '{"foo":"lorem","bar":"ipsum"}' | xidel -se '$json'
{
  "foo": "lorem",
  "bar": "ipsum"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) can be used to pretty print JSON

```bash
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | yq -o json
```

It has an option to define the indent

```bash
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | yq -o json --indent 3
```

You can choose between coloured and monochrome output

```bash
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | yq -o json --colors
```

```bash
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | yq -o json --no-colors
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visualize json log at console you can use  [munia-pretty-json](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/munia-pretty-json)

```sh
npm install -g munia-pretty-json
```

Your json data (app-log.json)

```
{"time":"2021-06-09T02:50:22Z","level":"info","message":"Log for pretty JSON","module":"init","hostip":"192.168.0.138","pid":123}
{"time":"2021-06-09T03:27:43Z","level":"warn","message":"Here is warning message","module":"send-message","hostip":"192.168.0.138","pid":123}
```

Run the command:

```
munia-pretty-json app-log.json
```

Here is readable output on console:

[image]

You can format the output with the template. The default template is `'{time} {level -c} {message}'`

Using template:

```
munia-pretty-json -t '{module -c} - {level} - {message}' app-log.json
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Agree about `jq`. You can add the following function to your `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```sh
jqless () {
  args=$1
  shift
  jq --color-output . $args "$@" | less --raw-control-chars
}
```

This allows an arbitrary number of input JSON files.

Answer (score 0):

Found 4 already available tools in my Gentoo system:

From package `dev-libs/json-glib` 19K ELF

```bash
json-glib-format -p file.json
```

From package `dev-lang/perl` 4,9K Perl script

(keeps unicode symbols as-is)

```bash
cat file.json | json_pp
```

From package `dev-libs/yajl` 43K ELF

```bash
cat file.json | json_reformat
```

From package `dev-lang/python`

(escapes unicode symbols to unreadable \u hex notation, had to replace `python` with `python3` on debian system)

```bash
python -m json.tool file.json
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use online tools instead if that is an option for you.

I find http://jsonprettyprint.net to be the simplest and easiest.

Answer (score -3):

I know that the original post asked for a shell script, but there are so many useful and irrelevant answers that probably did not help the original author.
Adding on to irrelevance :)

BTW I could not get any command line tools to work.

If somebody want simple JSON JavaScript code, they could do:

```
JSON.stringfy(JSON.parse(str), null, 4)
```

http://www.geospaces.org/geoweb/Wiki.jsp?page=JSON%20Utilities%20Demos

Here is JavaScript code that not only pretties the JSON, but orders them by their attribute or by attribute and level.

If input is

```json
{ "c": 1, "a": {"b1": 2, "a1":1 }, "b": 1},
```

it either prints (groups all the objects together):

```json
{
     "b": 1,
     "c": 1,
     "a": {
          "a1": 1,
          "b1": 2
     }
}
```

OR (just orders by key):

```json
{
 "a": {
      "a1": 1,
      "b1": 2
 },
 "b": 1,
 "c": 1
}
```