# Is Google data source JSON not valid?

Tags: python, simplejson

I am implementing a Google data source using their [Python library](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/gviz_api_lib.html#tojsonexample). I would like the response from the library to be able to be imported in another Python script using the [simplejson library.](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.0.9/docs/index.html)

However, even their [example](http://google-visualization.appspot.com/python/dynamic_example) doesn't validate in JSONLint:

```
{cols:
    [{id:'name',label:'Name',type:'string'},
     {id:'salary',label:'Salary',type:'number'},
     {id:'full_time',label:'Full Time Employee',type:'boolean'}],
rows:
    [{c:[{v:'Jim'},{v:800,f:'$800'},{v:false}]},
     {c:[{v:'Bob'},{v:7000,f:'$7,000'},{v:true}]},
     {c:[{v:'Mike'},{v:10000,f:'$10,000'},{v:true}]},
     {c:[{v:'Alice'},{v:12500,f:'$12,500'},{v:true}]}]}
```

How do I tweak the simplejson 'loads' function to import the above JSON content? I think the main problem is that the object keys are not strings.

I would rather not write a regular expression to convert the keys to strings since I think such code would be annoying to maintain.

I am currently getting an "Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)" error when trying to import the above JSON into Python with simplejson.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is considered to be invalid JSON without the string keys.

```
{id:'name',label:'Name',type:'string'}
```

must be:

```
{'id':'name','label':'Name','type':'string'}
```

According to the [Google Data Source](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/implementing_data_source.html#jsondatatable) page, they're returning invalid JSON.  They don't specifically say it, but all their examples lack quotes on the keys.

Here is a fairly complete list of [JSON processors for Python](http://deron.meranda.us/python/comparing_json_modules/basic) which goes into detail about what formats they support, and how well.  Most don't support non-string keys, **but it appears that [demjson](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/) will convert it.**

```
easy_install demjson
```

Comment: JSON expects strings as keys, not python dictionaries e.g., {1:1, 2:4} is a valid python dictionary but it is an invalid JSON. `{id:1}` and `{"id":1}` is a valid Javascript.

Comment: To be clear, I meant that the example shown is not a valid python dictionary.  Index numbers are legal, but any names must be strings.  {id:1} is valid Javascript but invalid Python.