# JSON command line formatter tool for Linux

Tags: linux, json

Is there an editor or tool for Linux command line to format JSON data?

Comment: I have implemented my own in CoffeeScript to run using Node.js: http://skovalyov.blogspot.com/2012/09/json-format-command-line-utility.html

Comment: `jq` is great. You have jQuery like interface for JSON (it's homepage say it's sed for JSON) http://stedolan.github.io/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json

Answer (score 107):

```
 alias pp='python -mjson.tool'
 pp mydata.json
```

From the first link in the accepted answer: http://ruslanspivak.com/2010/10/12/pretty-print-json-from-the-command-line/

Modern distros may require `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: Outdated answer. Use jq.

Comment: not work for bool `true` and `false`, only work for `True` in python format.

Comment: This answer is not outdated, it continues to work with python3 -m json.tool. However, jq will give you pretty colors :)

Answer (score 87):

jq is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor.

http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

jq is like sed for JSON data – you can use it to slice and filter and map and transform structured data with the same ease that sed, awk, grep and friends let you play with text.

jq is written in portable C, and it has zero runtime dependencies. You can download a single binary, scp it to a far away machine, and expect it to work.

Comment: To me this solution seems the best: easy to install, and output keeps the order of attributes from input - this might be sometime very practical when authoring documentation as it supports better readability.  Typical use: `$ jq . data.json` (mind the dot after the `jq`).

Comment: jq is superb. note that this will not work. ```jq . data.json  > data.json```. which will overwrite itself. export to a temp file and overwrite existing.

Comment: Indeed jq is superb. Once you have jq installed, in Vim you can paste any JSON into a new buffer and run `:%!jq '.'` this pretty prints the JSON in the buffer. Source: [Vim: prettify JSON](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2018/02/28/vim-beautify-json/)

Answer (score 20):

On Ubuntu jsonlint is provided by `apt:python3-demjson`

Usage:

```
$ sudo apt install -y python3-demjson
$ jsonlint -f input.json > output.json
```

Comment: Great for when the JSON you're looking at doesn't conform to the spec. Other tools (`jq`, the Python `json` module) require completely conformant JSON for them to work.

Comment: It appears that in current packages the command installed with the "python-demjson" package is "jsonlint-py" instead of "jsonlint".

Comment: The apt package appears to be called `python3-demjson` by now. The command installed with this package is still called "jsonlint" however.

Answer (score 9):

Add to vimrc:

```
" Format JSON data
map <C-F6> :%!python -m json.tool<CR>
```

And you can use the shortcut CTRL+F6 to format json data

---

Or just under vim's command mode:

```
%!python -m json.tool
```

Comment: If you're using vim you can: `au FileType json set equalprg=python\ -m\ json.tool` and format with `=`.