# A list of useful Python commands for Vim?

Tags: python, vim, pretty-print, autoformatting

I was looking for a quick way to autoformat/pretty-print JSON in Vim the other day and found this great little command on Stack Overflow: [`:%!python -m json.tool`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-to-pretty-print-json-script)

That sent me on a search for a list of other Python tools to pretty-print common web files, but I couldn't find much. Is there a good resource/list of Python tools that they find particularly useful for cleaning up poorly formatted web stuff inside Vim (e.g. HTML, XML, JavaScript, etc.)?

Comment: very cool, and I hope to see more of these - excellent way to discover  features.

Comment: This is soliciting extended discussion, and of the form "I use this, what do you use?".  [See the FAQ for why this question is off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).  Might be okay w/ community wiki flag checked.

Comment: @Merlyn I see what you mean, but my intent actually was not to start a list of post with individual commands but to just find a link to a resource or wiki that had one already: for example "http://docs.python.org/cool-pretty-print-goodness.html". I'm new to Vim, switching over from TextMate, and when I found the JSON Python tool I was itching for more but couldn't find a proper resource with more.

Comment: If you're coming from textmate then you might be interesting in the [snipmate plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540).

Comment: Thanks @Keith. I've started playing with that a bit as well as [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) which is awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Python**

Are you just looking for a resource for Python one-liners? You could browse through [the Python standard library documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/) to find more inspiration.

Or simply google "python one-liners json.tool" to find additional resources.  For example, this Reddit post: *[Suggestion for a Python blogger: figure out what what all the stdlib **main** functionality is, and document it](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/fofan/suggestion_for_a_python_blogger_figure_out_what/)*

**Command line**

Vim supports more than just Python (e.g. [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#docs) as Keith suggested).  Any tool that can accept pipe/standard input will integrate well with Vim.

The `%` command just picks a range that contains the entire file, and `!` filters that range through an external program.

See `:help :%` and `:help :!`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I'm new to Vim and haven't played with Python at all so I'm still trying get my bearings but it looks like I just need to play around with different utilities - Python or otherwise - and just find the ones that fit best into my workflow. Thanks for the links, that's exactly what I need - just a jumpstart to some helpful tools.

Answer (score 5):

For XHTML and XML files you can use tidy.

```
:%!tidy -i -asxhtml -utf8

:`<,`>!tidy -i -xml -utf8
```

The last one works on visual selections.

Comment: This looks promising! Are there other flags available for the tidy command? e.g. -javascript, -php, -ruby etc?

Comment: @johnmdonahue: It is called HTML tidy (tidy for short).  It is for HTML and now XML documents.  http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#docs

Comment: @Keith Right! Gotcha. I wasn't sure if there was an extended tidy/pretty-print for other langs as well. Looks like I'll just need to assemble a bit of a tool set for whichever language I need to work with. Still getting the lay of the Vim land here. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Vim has a command to do it, `=` (equal), like in `ggvG=` will reindent the whole file. Try `:help =` for more info about how to use functions and external programs with `=`. The default configuration uses internal indenting rules which works for most file types.

Comment: =G worked fine for HTML but for Python I could see its breaking the logic by combining if block with rest of the function etc . I prefer the autopep8 route for this .

Answer (score 0):

`!autopep8 -i %` seems to work fine in `vim` . The `-i` switch is to over-write the existing file in place. Use `more @ autopep8 --help`.

There is a `vim` plugin for this if you really are thinking of being a power user. Outside of `vim` you can test it with `autopep8 -diff {filename} or autopep8 {filename}`.

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of good tools that are can convert text between the two formats:

1. par: for hard line wrapping.
2. pandoc: for HTML, LaTeX, rst, and Markdown
3. autopep8: for parsing Python code into an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and spitting it out as pep8 compliant.

   ...

Vim is designed to make use of such utilities by the powerful `formatprg` settings. That by default is mapped to the gq operator. It works well with Vim motions, Vim text objects, selections, etc.

For instance, I use the setting below for on my Python files

```
au FileType python setlocal formatprg=autopep8\ --indent-size\ 0\ -
```

John MacFarlne has [a good article](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html) about creating a specialised script using pandoc which you could stick in your vimrc.