# Syntax highlighting/colorizing cat

Tags: unix, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

Is there a method to colorize the output of `cat`, the way `grep` does.

For `grep`, in most consoles it displays a colored output highlighting the searched keywords. Otherwise, you can force it by calling `grep --color`
Is there a generic way to color the output of any program according to your personal choice.

From what I understand, the program itself is not responsible for the colors. It is the shell.

I am using the default shell in FreeBSD 5.2.1 which looks like it has never seen colors since epoch.

Comment: oh no. I don't want to display a binary. I just want to display the output of a binary in a colorized manner.

Comment: I edited to avoid the confusion regarding the term "binary"

Comment: I think that the answer by @buergi matches the question, and this is also supported by the number of upvotes it has. Consider changing the accepted answer.

Comment: The best solution is: `sudo apt-get install lolcat && echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z} | lolcat`

Comment: TL;DR(Correct me if I am wrong): [highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501509/6397520) (I use), [pygmentize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14799752/6397520), [bat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50220911/6397520), [vimcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20826100/6397520), [supercat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10039345/6397520), [ccat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30074374/6397520), [source-highlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30126756/6397520). For `less` use: `yourColorCatCommand yourFile | less -R`.

Comment: As @myfirstAnswer said, "bat" (batcat) is an alternative solution for "code highlighting" instead of `cat`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`cat` with syntax highlighting is simply out of scope. `cat` is not meant for that.
If you just want to have the entire content of some file coloured in some way (with the same colour for the whole file), you can make use of terminal escape sequences to control the color.

Here's a sample script that will choose the colour based on the file type (you can use something like this instead of invoking `cat` directly):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
fileType="$(file "$1" | grep -o 'text')"
if [ "$fileType" == 'text' ]; then
    echo -en "\033[1m"
else
    echo -en "\033[31m"
fi
cat $1
echo -en "\033[0m"
```

The above (on a terminal that supports those escape sequences) will print any text file as 'bold', and will print any binary file as red. You can use `strings` instead of `cat` for printing binary files and you can enhance the logic to make it suit your needs.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this. But I need something that would do it universally. Not just `cat`/`grep`/`any particular program`

Comment: Then you can simply pass the command to be executed as an argument to the script and replace the hard-coded `cat` invocation with some `$cmd` which is initialized as $1 if there are two arguments or a default if there's only one. Then you simply write: `colorful.sh grep file`.

Comment: "cat is not meant for that." Cat isn't meant for writing individual files to stdout either - it's for concatenation. But that still doesn't mean that writing individual files to stdout isn't useful. Not does that mean highlighting them isn't useful.

Comment: I tried, under cygwin `pygmentize` is not able to color. Any tips?

Answer (score 490):

I'd recommend `pygmentize` from the python package [`python-pygments`](http://pygments.org/). You may want to define the following handy alias (unless you use `ccat` from the ccrypt package).

```bash
alias ccat='pygmentize -g'
```

[image: Syntax highlighted cat output using pygmentize]

And if you want line numbers:

```bash
alias ccat='pygmentize -g -O style=colorful,linenos=1'
```

Add one of these above commands to `~/.bash_aliases` for permanent effect

Comment: Another solution is to use the linux [`highlight`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/highlight) command. `alias ccat='highlight -O ansi'`

Comment: step (1) `easy_install --install-dir=/your/pygmentize/path Pygments`, step (2) `alias ccat /your/pygmentize/path/pygmentize -g`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMHO. Adding to that, I aliased it as `alias dog='pygmentize -g'`, because dogs are cooler than cats!

Comment: You can add less -R to make the code scrollable: `#!/bin/bash \n pygmentize -g $1 | less -R`

Comment: I called my alias `nyancat`.

Comment: pygmentize works as expected, but unfortunately seems to be rather slow. :-/

Comment: How is it possible to connect it to `nano`?

Comment: BTW, pygmentize also supports monokai style, which makes it exactly what I wanted (i.e. Sublime Text-like highlighting).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe try `highlight` as suggested above - it's noticeably faster in my case.

Comment: Also, when using the `highlight` command in `alias` or a function, add the `--force` option to output even when it cannot guess what the filetype is.

Comment: Why `-g` ? I couldn't find any information in pygmentize's command line usage document about the option `-g`

Comment: According to `pygments -h`: `If -g is passed, attempt to guess the lexer from the file contents, or pass through as plain text if this fails (this can work for stdin).`

Comment: Don't forget to add the `alias` command to `~/.bashrc` if you don't want to repeat it every time you login

Comment: @EvanPurkhiser I just don't like the red javascript strings of `highlight`. I have never seen such JS syntax highlight, putting strings on vivid red.

Comment: I went for it... until I realized there is not a single style in default Pygments that works well on a dark background. All that I tried on Ubuntu output some elements in unreadable dark blue.

Answer (score 162):

### Options:

[**pygmentize**](http://pygments.org/) is good. I have an alias:

```sh
alias c='pygmentize -g'
```

but ***highlight*** is another widely available alternative is

```sh
alias cats='highlight -O ansi --force'
```

### Installation:

You may have to install `pygments` using one of these:

```sh
sudo apt install python-pygments
sudo pip install pygments
sudo easy_install Pygments #for Mac user
```

and for `highlight` package which is easily available on all distributions

```sh
sudo apt install highlight
sudo yum install highlight
```

- Bitbucket repo: https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main
- GitHub mirror: https://github.com/sglyon/pygments

### In Action:

I'm attaching shots for both down below for a good comparison in highlightings

Here is `pygmentize` in action:
[image: Pygmentize highlighting on python file]

and this is `highlight`:
[image: Highlight highlighting on python file]

Comment: Thanks! It seems a bit slow, any way to make it faster?

Comment: `highlight` worked great for my needs and installed easily, thanks. If you want to look at files without extensions (e.g. .bash_aliases) then add `--syntax=bash` in addition to `-O ansi` to force it.

Comment: # pip install Pygments # echo "alias catc='pygmentize -g'" >> "~/.bashrc" # close terminal # open terminal # catc test.js --- and perfect works :-) 

Comment: Is there a way to make "highlight" guess the input language, much like the `-g` switch does for "pygmentize"?

Comment: `highlight` is 34x faster than that python program. The power of the classical languages holds strong.

Comment: I also feel that `pygmentize` is very slow now a days. I guess most of the time must go in regex matching.

Comment: For `highlight`, you want to add `--force` to the alias, otherwise it will throw an error for file formats that it does not understand, while as `cat` replacement you want it to still show the output without highlighting, which is what `--force` does. All together: `alias cat="highlight -O ansi --force"`

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, I was looking for this kind of tool, awesome!

Comment: tried `highlight` but it give me some html output not the syntax highlighted content, 
[Imgur](https://imgur.com/Peio46v)
what is the problem? how could I fix it?

Comment: @Luke that's why  you should add the `-O ansi` the default is to output html :-)

Comment: `-O xterm256` provides more colours than `-O ansi`, if your terminal supports it

Comment: I just don't like the red javascript strings of `highlight`. I have never seen such JS syntax highlight, putting strings on vivid red.

Comment: @Alexander Klimetschek I wouldn't alias cat itself here. This might mess up its usage in pipe commands and scripts.

Answer (score 119):

From late April 2018 onwards:

> **[Bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) - A cat(1) clone with syntax highlighting and Git integration.**

The project is a cat clone with support for colors and customizations written in Rust. It offers not only syntax highlighting with multiple themes, but also Git integration. As described in the documentation:

> *bat tries to achieve the following goals*:
>
> - Provide beautiful, advanced syntax highlighting
> - Integrate with Git to show file modifications
> - Be a drop-in replacement for (POSIX) cat
> - Offer a user-friendly command-line interface

It is, needless to say, much faster than pygmentize and does not choke when confronted with large files.

Source code and [binary releases](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/releases) + [installation instructions](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat#installation) can be found in the Github repository, as well as a [comparison to alternative programs](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/blob/master/doc/alternatives.md).

Comment: What people forget to mention is that `bat` stays in interactive mode by default. For it to behave more like `cat`, use it with `-pp` argument. An alias like ```alias cat="bat -pp"``` is propably what people are looking for.

Comment: I've been using pygmentize for colorizing cat before, but the solution with bat is much better suited for large files (logs of several MB), where pygmentize performance is subpar.

Comment: Great answer! Together with the -p option, and less paging, this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: bat is the coolest thing I've seen this week. This is awesome, thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is so much better than pygmentize, thank you !

Comment: Just what I needed. On ubuntu while installing using `apt install bat`, the command to use is `batcat`. For removing paging while preserving bat's excellent line formatting, the command is `batcat --paging "never" $file`.

Answer (score 44):

There are colorized versions of `cat` (their names are hard to google, unless you append `pager` and `github` or `cat replacement`).

- [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) [rust] https://github.com/sharkdp/bat (actively maintained)
- [ccat](https://github.com/jingweno/ccat/) [golang] https://github.com/jingweno/ccat/

Both `bat` and `ccat` are native binaries and are almost as fast as `/bin/cat` unlike Python-based solutions, such as [pygmentize](http://pygments.org/).

#### installing `bat`

- MacOS: `brew install bat`
- Linux: `apt install bat`
- Windows: `choco install bat`
- Binaries: https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/releases
- Build from source: `cargo install --locked bat` (requires [`cargo`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/getting-started/installation.html), the rust build tools)

> see steps for more OS's at https://github.com/sharkdp/bat#installation

#### Installing `ccat`

- get [the binaries for Linux/Windows/macOS](https://github.com/jingweno/ccat/releases) and copy **ccat** for example to `/usr/local/bin`.
- Mac: `brew install ccat`

If there is no binary for your platform (e.g. raspberry pi, etc) then you can install from source (requires the [golang](https://golang.org/doc/install) environment):

```bash
go get -u github.com/jingweno/ccat

# NOTE: as of Go 1.18 instead of 'go get xyz' use 'go install xyz', e.g.
go install github.com/jingweno/ccat@latest
```

##### Aliasing to `cat`

The ootb configuration of `bat` shows line numbers and does paging which I didn't need so I aliased it to disable the feature I didn't want:

Add in your `~/.bashrc` (`~/.zshrc`, etc..):

```bash
alias cat="bat --paging=never -pp --style='plain' --theme=TwoDark $*"
```

For `ccat`:

```bash
alias cat="ccat $*"
```

In cases when you need the plain ottb `cat` you can still invoke the unaliased version by prefixing with a backslash, e.g.

```bash
\cat /etc/hosts
```

or using the absolute path:

```bash
/bin/cat /etc/hosts
```

Comment: What's the proper repo name? apt-get ccat in Ubuntu 16 gives me some sort of encryption program and somewhat hilariously bricked my terminal as it's currently trying to encrypt or decrypt my entire proc directory...

Comment: @KatasticVoyage: my bad: for some reason I assumed it was in the repos, and I forgot how I got it in my ubuntu box. See the updated answer.

Comment: Currently, it seems like `brew install ccat` is enough, no need to `brew tap` anymore.

Comment: Yeah, `ccat` isn't the best name choice as `ccat` is already part of `ccrypt`.

Comment: I really enjoy how `bat --help` colorizes its own usage information.

Comment: I also think that `bat` was the easiest to install from its project release.

One must only establish an alias which instructs `bat` to not use paging, if one intends to use it as a drop-in replacement for `cat`: `alias cat='bat --paging=never'`

Comment: I really enjoyed the `bat` application, thanks!

Answer (score 43):

`vimcat` is single-file (shell script) and works good:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4325

Last update is from December 2013. Hint: you can force file type recognition by `vimcat -c "set ft=<type>"`.

Comment: One thing that is really nice about vimcat (or vimpager) is that it will respect the colorscheme you have defined in your `~/.vimrc` so syntax highlighting will be the same both when wanting to edit (vim) or print out (vimcat). Note that an updated version of vimcat can be found in the [vimpager repositiory](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager/blob/master/vimcat).

Comment: [Amaynut's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31971848/938111) is older and similar

Comment: `vimpager` doesn't use my vim colorscheme.

Comment: In my quick unscientific test, `vimcat` (1~2 second execution time) is much slower than `pymentize` (~200ms), which is much slower than `highlight` (~20ms), which is much slower than `cat` (~2ms). On the other hand, `vimcat` handles more file types and is more accurate than `hightlight` and `pygmentize`, and it is still faster than first `vim` then `:q`. So it earns my pick for this specific task.

Comment: @olibre This answer seems older than the one from Amaynut.

Answer (score 34):

The tool you're looking for is probably [supercat](http://supercat.nosredna.net/) (here's a [quick introduction](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1005732) published by Linux Journal).

I realize that this answer is late, and that it doesn't fully meet the OP requirements. So I'm adding it just for reference (it could be useful for other people looking for how to colorize text file output).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work so easily, I installed it and used the example config, but that had no colour effect

Comment: Nice, everything else is too slow. This is good. For help with configuration, see https://manpages.debian.org/testing/supercat/spc.1.en.html

Comment: Additionally for some configs for various languages: https://github.com/tanderson92/supercat/tree/master/spcrc

Answer (score 16):

The best way and the easiest way to do it if you have vim in your machine is to use `vimcat` which comes with `vimpager` program.

1. Install vimpage with

   `git clone git://github.com/rkitover/vimpager 
   cd vimpager 
   sudo make install`
2. Run vimcat:

   `vimcat index.html`

Comment: I love the idea, but vimcat is among the slower ones here. It's about as slow as pygmentize. 15x slower than `highlight` and 3x slower than `bat` for a 30-line bash script on my machine.

Comment: `vimcat` is a very nice solution. However, when I use an example (`vimcat afile.md`) I have to press any key to see the result. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13):

### `source-highlight`

Maybe it's possible to  find interesting `source-highlight` [released under GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/): a  package different from `highlight`.

Excerpt from `apt-cache show  source-highlight`:

> Description-en: **convert source code to syntax highlighted document.**
> This program, given a source file, produces a document with syntax
> highlighting.
> **It supports syntax highlighting for over 100 file formats** ...
> For output, the following formats are supported: HTML,
> XHTML, LaTeX, Texinfo, **ANSI color escape sequences**, and DocBook

I did some alias (Cat and PCat, see below) and this is their output

[image: Screen Example]

You can install on Debian based with

```
sudo apt-get install source-highlight
```

and add it as alias e.g. in your `.bash_aliases` with something like the line below.

```bash
alias Cat='source-highlight --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i'  
Cat myfile.c # or myfile.xml ...
```

Or you can do a similar alias (without the `-i`at the end to have the possibility to *pipe in*)

```bash
alias PCat='source-highlight --out-format=esc -o STDOUT '
tail myfile.sh | PCat     # Note the absence of the `-i`
```

Among the options that it's possible to read from `man source-highlight` the **`-s`** underlines that is possible to select, or *force*, the highlighting by command line or to leave to the program this duty:

> **-s**, **--src-lang**=STRING source language (use --lang-list to get the complete list).  **If not specified, the source language  will  be guessed from the file extension**.

> --lang-list
> list all the supported language and associated language definition file

Comment: If you want to also colorize `less` with `source-highlight`, someone on [GitHub](https://github.com/jrunning/source-highlight-solarized) gives the answer : `export LESSOPEN="| source-highlight -f esc -i %s -o STDOUT"` and `export LESS=" -R "`. Very useful when `pygmentize` is not available and cannot be installed.

Comment: @hastur pcat is not working for me. `source-highlight: missing feature: language inference requires input file`

Comment: @KhurshidAlam Maybe it is not one of the supported language. Try _`--lang-list` list all the supported language and associated language definition file_. Check if the language is supported, or force one enough similar... (BTW without your command line it is diffucult to guess what happened). It can even be a bad guess from the )"extension"_. Good Luck.

Answer (score 9):

[bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat#syntax-highlighting) precisely does that and can be aliased to cat `alias cat='bat'`

Comment: bat is realllly nice, written in Rust so very performant and safe. Love the colors and cleanness. I recommend the flag -p as in `bat -p yourFileName`

Answer (score 7):

> > From what I understand, the binary itself is not responsible for the colors. It is the shell.

That't not correct. Terminal just interprets the color codes that is output to the terminal. Depending on its capability it can ignore certain formatting/coloring codes.

From man page it does not seem cat supports coloring its output. Even if it were to support coloring like grep what should it color in the text file? Syntax highlighting required knowledge of underlying language which is not in the scope of simple utility like cat.

You can try more powerful editors like vim,emacs, gedit etc on unix platform if seeing the code highlighted is your goal.

Comment: “`cat` isn't for printing files with line numbers, it isn't for compressing multiple blank lines, it's not for looking at non-printing ASCII characters, it's for concatenating files.” – from [UNIX Style, or cat -v Considered Harmful](http://harmful.cat-v.org/cat-v).

Answer (score 7):

On OSX simply do `brew install ccat`.

https://github.com/jingweno/ccat. Like cat but displays content with syntax highlighting. Built in Go.

Comment: Nice. Has some language limitations but it does feel a lot faster than pygments.

Comment: [ccat](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ccat/) can also be found in the AUR repository of Arch Linux. Use yaourt or pacaur to install the package.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, just answering for the record to provide the solution I ended up using.  Perhaps this is a bit hacky (probably not the original intent of the parameter), but:

alias cgrep='grep -C 9000'

cat whatever | cgrep 'snozzberries'

..`grep -C N` will provide N lines of context above and below the found item.  If it's larger than the input, the whole input is included.  In this case, we just make sure it's larger than any typical terminal output we'll want to look at manually, which is generally what you're looking to do if highlighting.

**EDIT :**  However, this solution suggested below by Beni Cherniavsky-Paskin is superior -- it matches (and highlights) either the word you're looking for or the beginning of the line (not highlightable).  The net result is exactly what you want.

```bash
cat whatever | egrep 'snozzberries|$'
```

That's the new best solution I've seen for that problem, thanks Beni.

Comment: A more robust way to highlight a pattern while including all lines is `egrep 'snozzberries|$'`

Answer (score 3):

In this question https://superuser.com/questions/602294/is-there-colorizer-utility-that-can-take-command-output-and-colorize-it-accordin `grcat`/`grc` tool was recommended as alternative to [`supercat`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1005732).

Man of [grc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/grc.1.html) and of [`grcat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/grcat.1.html); it is part of [grc package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/gutsy/+package/grc) ([sources](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grc/1.1)):

> grc - frontend for generic colouriser grcat(1)
>
> grcat  -  read  from standard input, colourise it and write to standard  output

Answer (score 1):

I have written the small script to perform the colourization using `pygmentize`.

```bash
colorize_via_pygmentize() {
    if [ ! -x "$(which pygmentize)" ]; then
        echo "package \'Pygments\' is not installed!"
        return -1
    fi

    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        pygmentize -g $@
    fi

    for FNAME in $@
    do
        filename=$(basename "$FNAME")
        lexer=`pygmentize -N \"$filename\"`
        if [ "Z$lexer" != "Ztext" ]; then
            pygmentize -l $lexer "$FNAME"
        else
            pygmentize -g "$FNAME"
        fi
    done
}
```

And then make an alias to script. `alias cat=colorize_via_pygmentize`. Also dont forget to save this in **~/.bashrc**.

Answer (score 1):

Just use vim and [this vimrc file](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_vim_as_a_syntax-highlighting_pager).

oneliner:

```bash
vim -c '1' -c 'set cmdheight=1' -c 'set readonly' -c 'set nomodifiable' -c 'syntax enable' -c 'set guioptions=aiMr' -c 'nmap q :q!<CR>' -c 'nmap <Up> <C-Y>' -c 'nmap <Down> <C-E>' -c 'nmap ^V <C-F><C-G>' "$@"
```

`nano -v` may also be an alternative.

Comment: Hi, this seems like the `less` command. What we need is `cat`. BTW: when you have colored `cat` command, you can use `less -R` as in `someColorCatCommand someFile | less -R`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small Rust-based software to do exactly that. It is named `highlighter` and can be found in the following repo:

https://codeberg.org/mehrad/highlighter

Basically you just pipe the output of the previous command into it and tell it to color it based on your preference. For example:

```bash
locale | highlighter  --blue="=" --red="_U.*" --yellow "NAME" --green="_ME.*"
```

[image]

I suggest creating an alias to it if you think the name is too long. I'd rather go with a longer but descriptive name than a short ambiguous one.

Answer (score 0):

Place in your `~/.bashrc`

```bash
function ccat() { docker run -it -v "$(pwd)":/workdir -w /workdir whalebrew/pygmentize $1; }
```

then

```bash
ccat filename
```

> [Whalebrew](https://github.com/whalebrew/whalebrew) creates aliases for Docker images so you can run them as if they were native commands. It's like Homebrew, but with Docker images.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want a one liner to set `cat` output to a given color, you can append

`alias cat="echo -en 'code' | cat - "`

to your `~/.$(basename $SHELL)rc`

Here is a gist with color codes: https://gist.github.com/chrisopedia/8754917

I like `'\e[1;93m'`, which is high intensity yellow. It looks like this: [image]

Comment: Hi, I don't think this was the OP question. I think the question was not to color all text in one color, but to color in different colors according to specific program language.

Comment: @myfirstAnswer I don't think so, OP is asking for a way to color like grep, and grep uses one color. The other answers are instead focused on syntax highlighting, which is not what OP asked for.

Comment: @myfirstAnswer In fact if you read the accepted answer you will see a discussion where OP is looking for a way to set one color for the whole output. But thank you for reading my answer and giving me feedback.

Comment: @myfirstAnswer It's not really worth your time. It's an old question and the answer has been selected. Good bye.

Answer (score -1):

This question is exceedingly old, but I stumbled on it anyway.  For completeness' sake, the question asked "is there a way to get `cat` to colorize its output?".  Yes, for ansi-encoded outputs, you can add these exports to your .bashrc:

```bash
# colorful less output
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\e[1;32m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\e[1;32m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\e[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\e[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\e[01;33m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\e[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\e[1;4;31m'
```

This will colorize the output of ansi-encoded text, like terraform plan:
[image]

This is not, however, the same thing as `bat`, which can do better parsing of json, shows line numbers, and is generally a better user experience.