# How can I pretty-print a JSON file from the command line?

Tags: json, shell, command-line

I've a file with a sequence of JSON element:

```
{ element0: "lorem", value0: "ipsum" }
{ element1: "lorem", value0: "ipsum" }
...
{ elementN: "lorem", value0: "ipsum" }
```

Is there a shell script to format JSON to display file content in a readable form?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-from-the-command-line) post, and I think is a good starting point!

My idea is to iterate rows in the file and then:

```
while read row; do echo ${row} | python -mjson.tool; done < "file_name"
```

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pretty-print JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json)

Comment: You can just do `cat somefile.json | jq .` to pretty-print the file (assuming you have jq installed).

Comment: It's important to note that the OP *says* "JSON" but actually means Newline-Delimited JSON (NDJSON), with no comma between top level objects.  (This is common in JSON-based logging frameworks.)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Pipe the results from the file into the python json tool 2.6 onwards

```
python -m json.tool < 'file_name'
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this for all files in a directory? I'm not used to bash scripting yet.

Comment: add `alias ppjson="python -m json.tool"` to your `~/.profile` file to avoid coming back here next time you need this

Comment: This does not work for me !!  I get `Expecting property name: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`.  Python 2.7.16 on Linux with 4.4.0 kernel, Debian buster with `python` and `python-cjson` packages installed.

Answer (score 80):

### jq - a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor

I felt this deserved its own entry when it took me longer than it should have to discover. I was looking for a simple way to pretty-print the json output of `docker inspect -f`. It was mentioned  briefly above by Noufal Ibrahim as part of another answer.

From the jq website (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

> jq is like sed for JSON data - you can use it to slice and filter and map and transform structured data with the same ease that sed, awk, grep and friends let you play with text.

It provides colored output by default and you simply have to pipe to `jq`, e.g.

```
jq . < file
```

**Example:**

["Raw" json output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov1CT.png) vs [the same piped to jq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5SJE.png)

Comment: erratum : pipe to    jq '.'   as jq requires this minimal directive

Comment: `jq` has options to change indentation `--indent 2` and sort the keys in objects `--sort-keys` (which is very useful when checking JSON into a repository because then diffs are much more informative)

Answer (score 56):

You can use Python JSON tool (requires Python 2.6+).

For example:

```
echo '{ "element0" : "lorem", "element1" : "ipsum" }' | python -m json.tool
```

Which will give you:

```
{
    "element0": "lorem",
    "element1": "ipsum"
}
```

Answer (score 17):

From a mac OS 10.15 terminal I can use `json_pp`:

```
echo '{ "element0" : "lorem", "element1" : "ipsum" }' | json_pp
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, wish I could upvote more! 
Did the trick spot on for us.

Answer (score 13):

## Colored output using Pygmentize + Python json.tool

[Pygmentize](http://pygments.org/) is a killer tool. [See this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501509/2670370) I combine python json.tool with pygmentize

```
echo '{"foo": "bar"}' | python -m json.tool | pygmentize -g
```

For other similar tools and installation instruction see the answer linked above.

Here is a live demo:

[image: demo]

Comment: Nice! I didn't know pygmentize! But I had to install it first, then run command "....| pygmentize -l python", your command "... | pygmentize -g" didn't work for me (pretty print json but uncolered)

Answer (score 6):

There are a bunch of them. I personally have this alias in my `.zshrc`

```
pjson () {
        ~/bin/pjson.py | less -X
}
```

where `pjson.py` is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import sys

try:
    input_str = sys.stdin.read()
    print json.dumps(json.loads(input_str), sort_keys = True, indent = 2)
except ValueError,e:
    print "Couldn't decode \n %s \n Error : %s"%(input_str, str(e))
```

Allows me to use that in a command line as a pipe (something like `curl http://.... | pjson`).

OTOH, Custom code is a liability so there's [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/), which to me looks like the gold standard. It's written in C (and is hence portable with no dependencies like Python or Node), does much more than just pretty printing and is fast.

Comment: nice even this solution!

Comment: The python script is good, but why wrap it in a shell function in the first place?

Comment: so the solution is to add a bash script that will run a python script which will only work on your local machine ?

Comment: Jo So: I did that so that the pager would work with `-X`. It's useful to have a pager but by default, `less` clears the screen and things like that which are undesirable.

Comment: Nimrod007: Not really. It's just something in my stash of quick and dirty scripts. Works for me so I haven't bothered changing it. I also like the fact that it has a pager.

Comment: The really valuable thing in the answer is `jq` though. I think it's superior to all the solutions in this question.

Answer (score 6):

In the Mac OS, install `jq` with the command,

```
$ brew install jq
```

You can get the pretty print JSON as similar as,

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/appointments/1  | jq


  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   117    0   117    0     0   8404      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  9000
{
  "craeted_at": "10:24:38",
  "appointment_date": "2019-02-08",
  "name_of_doctor": "Monika",
  "status": true,
  "price": 12.5,
  "id": 1
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `jq` package which can be installed in all Linux systems. Install the tool using below commands.

```sh
# Redhat based systems(Centos)
yum install -y epel-release
yum install -y jq

# Debian based systems
apt install -y jq
```

Then you will be able to pipe text streams to the jq tool.

```sh
echo '{"test":"value", "test2":"value2"}' | jq
```

Hope this answer will help.

Comment: You'll need `epel-release` for CentOS 7

Answer (score 2):

Shawn's solution but for Python 3:

```
echo '{"foo": "bar"}' | python3 -m json.tool
```

Answer (score 1):

To format your JSON with proper indentation use `JSON.stringify`

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(your_object, null, 2)); // prints in b/w
```

But to make it prettier by adding colors, you can check out my package `beautify-json`

[beautify-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/beautify-json)

**Example**:

```
const { jsonBeautify } = require('beautify-json')

let your_object = {
    name: 'Nikhil',
    age: 22,
    isMarried: false,
    girlfriends: null,
    interestedIn: [
        'javascript',
        'reactjs',
        'nodejs'
    ]
}

jsonBeautify(your_object) // It will beautify your object with colors and proper indentation and display it on the terminal
```

**Output**:
[image: Screenshot of the beautified object printed in terminal]

Comment: I think the problem with the girlfriends is that you need to extend your interests a bit beyond programming. Have you thought of literature or poetry, or a sport like skydiving? But thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

## Formatting json as a table from the command line

You can use [jtab](https://github.com/wlezzar/jtab) - a tool written in rust - to print any json data as a table.

For example:

```
➜ echo '{"foo": "bar"}' | jtab

+-----+
| foo |
+-----+
| bar |
+-----+
```

It also works with a json array:

```
➜  echo '[{"id": "1", "name": "Rust"}, {"id": "2", "name": "Jtab"}]' | jtab

+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | Rust |
+----+------+
| 2  | Jtab |
+----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

with python (2 and 3):

```
alias prettify_json="python -c 'import sys ;import json ; print(json.dumps(json.loads(sys.stdin.read()), indent=4))'"
```

or with ruby:

```
alias prettify_json="ruby -e \"require 'json';puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(STDIN.read))\""
```

you can use:

```
echo '{"bar": "abc", "foo": "def"}' | prettify_json
```

```
curl http://.../file.json | prettify_json
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use json_reformat

```
echo '{"test":"value", "test2":"value2"}' | json_reformat

{
    "test": "value",
    "test2": "value2"
}
```

Could be installed by  apt-get install yajl
even under Windows in MobaXTerm