# How would a human read a json winston log file?

Tags: json, node.js, winston

It seems nice for API's, scripts and what not. But reading a winston json stack trace is very hard with a text editor. E.g.

```
{"level":"info","message":"starting","timestamp":"2014-05-14T15:45:44.334Z"}
{"date":"Wed May 14 2014 08:45:45 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)","process":{"pid":8804,"uid":null,"gid":null,"cwd":"C:\\data\\mytool","execPath":"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe","version":"v0.10.21","argv":["node","C:\\data\\mytool\\server"],"memoryUsage":{"rss":45199360,"heapTotal":32171264,"heapUsed":15158096}},"os":{"loadavg":[0,0,0],"uptime":70496.6138252},"trace":[{"column":null,"file":null,"function":"Object.parse","line":null,"method":"parse","native":true},{"column":32,"file":"C:\\data\\mytool\\src\\status.js","function":"Request._callback","line":166,"method":"_callback","native":false},{"column":22,"file":"C:\\data\\mytool\\node_modules\\request\\request.js","function":"Request.self.callback","line":122,"method":"self.callback","native":false},{"column":17,"file":"events.js","function":"Request.EventEmitter.emit","line":98,"method":"EventEmitter.emit","native":false},{"column":14,"file":"C:\\data\\mytool\\node_modules\\request\\request.js","function":"","line":888,"method":null,"native":false},{"column":20,"file":"events.js","function":"Request.EventEmitter.emit","line":117,"method":"EventEmitter.emit","native":false},{"column":12,"file":"C:\\data\\mytool\\node_modules\\request\\request.js","function":"","line":839,"method":null,"native":false},{"column":20,"file":"events.js","function":"IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit","line":117,"method":"EventEmitter.emit","native":false},{"column":16,"file":"_stream_readable.js","function":null,"line":920,"method":null,"native":false},{"column":13,"file":"node.js","function":"process._tickCallback","line":415,"method":"_tickCallback","native":false}],"stack":["SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input","    at Object.parse (native)","    at Request._callback (C:\\data\\mytool\\src\\status.js:166:32)","    at Request.self.callback (C:\\data\\mytool\\node_modules\\request\\request.js:122:22)","    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)","    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\\data\\mytool\\node_modules\\request\\request.js:888:14)","    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)","    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\\data\\mytool\\node_modules\\request\\request.js:839:12)","    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)","    at _stream_readable.js:920:16","    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)"],"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException: Unexpected end of input","timestamp":"2014-05-14T15:45:45.228Z"}
```

Answer (score 24):

Simply set the file transport "json" property to false, and you'll get a human readable log. Same as you see in the console.

```
    var winston = require('winston');
    var logger = new winston.Logger({
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({
          json: false,
          filename:'log.log'
        }),
        new winston.transports.Console()
      ],
      exitOnError: false
    });
   logger.log('info', 'some msg');
```

Comment: Just to clarify - I haven't accepted this answer because it removes the json from the log. I want to keep the json log but use a viewer to make reading it easier.

Comment: @ubershmekel Have you found the solution now? I also need to see pretty printed logs in Winston but stored as json format. It seems bunyan cli has that ability but I don't know if Winston has similar feature.

Comment: I use `bunyan` to log which comes with a command line tool you can use which behaves like a colorized `less` for its json logs. Maybe the cli works with winston logs too, not sure.

Answer (score 18):

Pass it through [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/), which is like sed for JSON. E.g.:

```
jq . file.log
```

Comment: To tail the log file, use `tail -f file.log | jq --unbuffered .`.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just run it through a [JSON formatter on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265439/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-from-the-command-line-from-a-file) ?

e.g. (example from the link above)

```
echo '{ element0: "lorem", element1: "ipsum" }' | python -mjson.tool
```

An alternative may be to look at building a shell script around the above tool (or perhaps) [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to perform some custom stack trace parsing

Comment: Thanks for that bit, though `python -m json.tool` only knows how to digest one line. Still, looking at the results e.g. http://pastebin.com/16AE7Qn7 isn't exactly as nice as looking at a text log stack trace. Not to mention having to scroll through a million of these.

Comment: It would perhaps be worth looking at building a shell script around the above tool (or perhaps) *jq* to perform some custom stack trace parsing. Answer amended...

Comment: As of Python 3.8, `json.tool` now accepts the json-lines format via the option `--json-lines` so that each new line gets interpreted as a separate json object: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#cmdoption-json-tool-json-lines

Answer (score 4):

You should try [winston-logs-display](https://github.com/ash-developer/winston-logs-display) .

Demo Output:

[image: winston-logs-display output]

Also [Log.io](https://github.com/NarrativeScience/Log.io) is good option for this. it supports winston log.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Keen.IO](https://keen.io/) - their CLI tool can upload the line-deliminated JSON, then you can use their 'Explorer' to filter/view log events.

`keen events:add --collection myLogs --file winston-output.json`

Answer (score 1):

Seems node's [bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) has features that let you filter and view json logs in a human readable way with a [CLI](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#cli-usage).

```
$ node hi.js | bunyan -l warn
[2013-01-04T19:08:37.182Z]  WARN: myapp/40353 on banana.local: au revoir (lang=fr)
```

[image: bunyan CLI output]

Comment: You're right and I haven't accepted my answer because of that. Though it does solve my need to log json and consume that json.

Answer (score 1):

It's slow but your shell can do it, get formatted, colourized JSON.

```
./thing | ndjson
```

[image: asciicast]

### How?

You run some JSON formatting command on each line, `bash` or `zsh` syntax is:

```
./thing | while read in ; do echo "$in" | python -m json.tool ; done
```

For `fish` the syntax is

```
./thing | while read in; echo "$in" | python -mjson.tool; end #fish
```

To make it extra fancy, just `pip install pygments`.

Define a handy alias `pp`, so you run `cat file.json | pp`.

```
alias pp="python -mjson.tool | pygmentize -l js"
```

And then define `ndjson`

```
alias ndjson='while read in; do echo "$in" | pp; done'
```

Now you can type the following to get formatted, colourized JSON.

```
./thing | ndjson
```

(use `funced` and `funcsave` to define alias in `fish`)

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps (so many years after the last response), I synthesized the one-line command which allows even python 2.7 to take the live-one-line-at-a-time output of `tail -f winston.log` and pipe it through python's json.tool for pretty-printing.

```
tail -f winston.log | while read -r line; do echo -n "$line" | python -m json.tool; done
```

(Note that if you are using python 3.8 and beyond, the parameter `--json-lines`, when supplied to json.tool, should eliminate the need of the while..do potion).

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late on this but there is an easy way.

1. Open a new tab in your browser
2. Open devtools
3. Run this code

```js
const entries = prompt('Log Data').split('\n').map(JSON.parse);

console.table(entries);
```

Enter your log data into the prompt and press enter.

Now you have an interactive table view of the log entries. You can click the headers to sort and even right click for some options. You can also resize columns.

To view certain entries, do

```js
console.log(entries.filter(entry => entry.foo.bar > 323)); // Just an example, you can do anything with the array
```

View devtools in full screen to see more of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I use [lnav](http://lnav.org/): I supports json-logs to some extend: i.e. you can easily define your own [log-format](https://docs.lnav.org/en/latest/formats.html#defining-a-new-format). This way you can optimize the display to your needs (i.e. so that it matches your winston log-output.

Here is a simple example for our lnav-log-config:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://lnav.org/schemas/format-v1.schema.json",
  "winston": {
    "title": "My Custom Json log format",
    "description": "Custom JSON-log format for winston",
    "url": "https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#formats",
    "file-pattern": "\\.jsonlog",
    "json": true,
    "level-field": "level",
    "timestamp-field": "timestamp",
    "body-field": "message",
    "line-format": [
      {
        "field": "__timestamp__"
      },
      " ",
      {
        "field": "__level__",
        "text-transform": "uppercase"
      },
      " ",
      {
        "field": "message"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

NOTE: that I use `"file-pattern": "\\.jsonlog",`: change or remove this as needed.

[lnav](http://lnav.org/) even works in my WSL2.
Installation as usual: `sudo apt install lnav`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by writing a npm package (usage: `tail -f logFile.log | npx winston-log-viewer`)  you can see full description here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68455246/4650625

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visualize winston json log at console you can use  [munia-pretty-json](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/munia-pretty-json)

Your json data (app-log.json)

```
{"time":"2021-06-09T02:50:22Z","level":"info","message":"Log for pretty JSON","module":"init","hostip":"192.168.0.138","pid":123}
{"time":"2021-06-09T03:27:43Z","level":"warn","message":"Here is warning message","module":"send-message","hostip":"192.168.0.138","pid":123}
```

Run the command:

```
munia-pretty-json app-log.json
```

Here is readable output on console:

[image]

You can format the output with the template. The default template is `'{time} {level -c} {message}'`

Using template:

```
munia-pretty-json -t '{module -c} - {level} - {message}' app-log.json
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In file s.log

```json
{"level":"info","message":{"duration":0,"params":"[0]","query":"SELECT \"public\".\"User\".\"id\", \"public\".\"User\".\"nama\", \"public\".\"User\".\"umur\", \"public\".\"User\".\"photo_profile\", \"public\".\"User\".\"alamat\", \"public\".\"User\".\"email\", \"public\".\"User\".\"password\" FROM \"public\".\"User\" WHERE 1=1 OFFSET $1","target":"quaint::connector::metrics","timestamp":"2024-01-14T14:24:17.136Z"}}
{"level":"info","message":{"duration":3,"params":"[0]","query":"SELECT \"public\".\"User\".\"id\", \"public\".\"User\".\"nama\", \"public\".\"User\".\"umur\", \"public\".\"User\".\"photo_profile\", \"public\".\"User\".\"alamat\", \"public\".\"User\".\"email\", \"public\".\"User\".\"password\" FROM \"public\".\"User\" WHERE 1=1 OFFSET $1","target":"quaint::connector::metrics","timestamp":"2024-01-14T14:24:19.958Z"}}
```

Code for read json in file

```js
import fs from 'node:fs'
import {dirname} from 'path'

// fs.readFile()
fs.readFile(dirname('')+"/s.log",(err,data)=>{
        let buf = Buffer.from(data)
        let str_ = String(buf).split('\n')
        let array_of_logger = []
        
        for(let x = 0 ; x < str_.length; x++){
            array_of_logger.push(JSON.parse(str_[x].replace('\r','')))
        }

        console.log(array_of_logger);
  
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).