# Is there a way to show winston log files like we show it in bunyan CLI?

Tags: node.js, logging, tail, winston, bunyan

In [Bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) logger we can see the log files like this:
`tail -f sample.log | bunyan` and show the logs colorful and show json objects pretty, but I couldn't find some thinkg like that solution in [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) logger, any body has idea about that?

Comment: amend the default console transport like so: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#common-transport-options

Comment: Yeah console transport is good, but I want to use my log files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a tiny npm package based on Bunyan CLI for pretty printing winston logs, you can use that in this way:

- `npm i -g winston-log-viewer`
- `tail -f logFile.log | winston-log-viewer`

Or

- `tail -f logFile.log | npx winston-log-viewer`

https://github.com/mohammadranjbarz/winston-log-viewer

[image]

Comment: A nice project for json log visualization.

Comment: Great little tool, pairs well with GitBash if you're on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to winston-log-viewer I had created [munia-pretty-json](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/munia-pretty-json) and using it for many projects. You can visualize any json log at console.

```sh
npm install -g munia-pretty-json
```

Your json data (app-log.json)

```
{"time":"2021-06-09T02:50:22Z","level":"info","message":"Log for pretty JSON","module":"init","hostip":"192.168.0.138","pid":123}
{"time":"2021-06-09T03:27:43Z","level":"warn","message":"Here is warning message","module":"send-message","hostip":"192.168.0.138","pid":123}
```

Run the command:

```
munia-pretty-json app-log.json
```

Or tail the json file:

```
tail -f app-log.json | munia-pertty-json
```

Here is readable output on console:

[image]

You can format the output with the template. The default template is `'{time} {level -c} {message}'`

Using template:

```
munia-pretty-json -t '{module -c} - {level} - {message}' app-log.json
```

Output:

[image]