# How to pretty json output from curl?

Tags: curl

I am trying to do this:

`curl localhost:3000/api/items/15/tools`

This is the return right now:

> {"recipe_tools":[{"id":19,"name":"Cutting
>   Board","prices":{"display":"$49.99","value":"49.99"},"description":"Built
>   to last,
>   ... (and then like a million lines)

And it keeps going...

How do I pretty print or awesome print this? What can I do?

Comment: Within `curl`? You can't; it doesn't. There are _plenty_ of tools you could pipe some JSON into and format it though. As such, I would suggest this is actually a software recommendation request.

Comment: You learn how to parse the object that is returned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pretty-print JSON from the command line? (from a file)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265439/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-from-the-command-line-from-a-file)

Comment: What's your scripting language?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pretty-print JSON in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are things you can install, but the simplest way is to use Python as it's typically already installed.

```
curl localhost:3000/api/items/15/tools | python -m json.tool
```

Answer (score 2):

Port 3000 makes me think you are using Rails.

I have used `JSON.pretty_generate(json_obj)` on my RoR applications to have a JSON object return properly indented.

Answer (score 2):

I use [jq](https://github.com/jqlang/jq) to pretty-print it.

> `jq` is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor.

> `jq` is written in portable C, and it has zero runtime dependencies.

E.g.

Without JSON formatter

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:3000; echo
{"account":{"id":"HXRC","uri":["mailto:Lizzie.Koepp@hotmail.com","tel:366-643-7219"],"features":["585"],"nickname":"Consultant"}}
```

Install `jq`(Ubuntu):

```
$ sudo apt-get install jq
```

Use `jq` json formatter.

```js
$ curl -s http://localhost:3000 | jq '.'
{
  "account": {
    "id": "HXRC",
    "uri": [
      "mailto:Lizzie.Koepp@hotmail.com",
      "tel:366-643-7219"
    ],
    "features": [
      "585"
    ],
    "nickname": "Consultant"
  }
}
```

You can find more examples in [tutorial](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/tutorial/). You can find the installation for each OS in [download](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/download/) page

Comment: `jq` is also available through Homebrew, so `brew install jq`