# using alias ccat='pygmentize -g -O style=colorful,linenos=1' with line numbers

Tags: bash, alias, cat, pygmentize

I'm using [this alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14799752/3512538) to color my `cat` results. However, I want to add line numbers to the output, but using `ccat -n <filename>` is not working.

I can achieve it by `ccat <filename> | cat -n` but I can't create an alias for that (I expect an alias such as `ccatn` which I could use like `ccatn <filename>`)

What can I do to get this functionality (meaning, type in a command and a file name and get the same result as typing `ccat <filename> | cat -n`)?

Answer (score 1):

Use a function instead:

```
ccatn() {
    pygmentize -g -O style=colorful,linenos=1 "$1" | cat -n
}
```