# cat file to terminal and color a specific word

Tags: colors, terminal, grep, cat

I've read several posts that handle syntax highlighting, `cat` and `grep` (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851134/syntax-highlighting-colorizing-cat) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981601/colorized-grep-viewing-the-entire-file-with-highlighted-matches)) but haven't yet found what I'm looking for. I want to print **an entire text file to terminal**, and have a specific (repeating) word **colored in red**. Lines that do not have this word **should be printed out too**. Here's something that comes close, but only
prints lines that contain the specific word. This post doesn't show it, but the **load** word is colored red like it should.

```
$ cat input.ll | grep "load"
  %tmp = load %class.A*, %class.A** %p, align 8
  %vtable = load i32 (%class.A*, i32, i32, i32)**, i32 (%class.A*, i32, i32, i32)*** %tmp1, align 8
  %tmp2 = load i32 (%class.A*, i32, i32, i32)*, i32 (%class.A*, i32, i32, i32)** %vfn, align 8
  %tmp3 = load i32, i32* @x, align 4
```

And here is the original file:

```
$ cat input.ll
  %tmp = load %class.A*, %class.A** %p, align 8
  %tmp1 = bitcast %class.A* %tmp to i32 (%class.A*, i32, i32, i32)***
  %vtable = load i32 (%class.A*, i32, i32, i32)**, i32 (%class.A*, i32, i32, i32)*** %tmp1, align 8
  %vfn = getelementptr inbounds i32 (%class.A*, i32, i32, i32)*, i32 (%class.A*, i32, i32, i32)** %vtable, i64 2
  %tmp2 = load i32 (%class.A*, i32, i32, i32)*, i32 (%class.A*, i32, i32, i32)** %vfn, align 8
  %tmp3 = load i32, i32* @x, align 4
  %call = call i32 %tmp2(%class.A* %tmp, i32 3, i32 %tmp3, i32 7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest with GNU grep:

```
grep --color -E 'load|$' file
```