# How to get pretty printing in json simple java library

Tags: json

Is there any way to get the pretty printing feature in json simple java library.Any example would be good.

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-to-pretty-print-json-script)

Answer (score 0):

you just want for developer's perspective then install **addons/extensions** for your browsers

or if you really want to beautify your code then try

http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I am using jackson-mapper-lgpl library.
There is DefaultPrettyPrinter that can help you.

Here is my Serializer:

```
public class JSONSerializer
{
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

public JSONSerializer() {
    this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();
}

public String serialize(Object ob) throws IOException
{
    if (ob == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Cannot serialize null value");
    }
    return mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(ob);
}
}
```