# Pretty printing invalid JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, pretty-print

There is a way to pretty-print valid JSON with Python : [How can I pretty-print JSON in (unix) shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-to-pretty-print-json-script)

However jsonlint.com pretty-prints JSON even if there is something wrong.

I want to do that, and I'm using Python. Does anyone know a script that does it ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Consider inspecting https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint which powers jsonlint.com for insights.

Comment: I have considered using this repo, but I'm required to use tools that run with Python only ... But that's exactly what i need though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a built-in way to do it with Python:

```
python -m json.tool myfile.json
```

Comment: If there is an error, it says where it is, but doesn't print back what I have. I'm interested in pretty-printing even if it's invalid. Any solution ?

Comment: Please consider my answer below

Answer (score 2):

[@kelw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835/keiw) has already pointed out `demjson`, which works well for slightly invalid JSON. For data that's even less JSON compliant I've written [`barely_json`](https://github.com/torfsen/barely_json):

```
from barely_json import parse
from pprint import pprint

invalid_json = '[no, , {complete: yes}]'
data = parse(invalid_json)
pprint(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [demjson](https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson) module either in your own script or `jsonlint.py` tool it prvides

Answer (score 1):

Try [jsbeautifier](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) library for beautifying JavaScript. It works because JSON is "almost" subset of JavaScript.

```
import json
import jsbeautifier

invalid_json = '{"hello": "world",}'

json.loads(invalid_json)
# ValueError: Expecting property name: line 4 column 1 (char 25)

jsbeautifier.beautify(invalid_json)
# '{\n    "hello": "world",\n}'
```