# How to set "aggregate column a" with setOptions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

In the chart editor there is an option to "Aggregate Column A".

How can I set this in a script using setOption?

Thanks

Comment: You want to use `setOption` from an AppScript service (eg. `EmbeddedChartService`) and use [Data Manipulation Methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#data-manipulation-methods) to Google Visualization API? You can use the `join()` method to 2 `DataTables` or if you're SQL-savvy, the `group()` method would do.

Comment: Thanks @adjuremods the data is already manipulated how I want. I was hoping that there would something easier to work with. Basically what's happening is the chart is creating a series when I have a fixed list of discrete values. i.e
`Val     Sum
1000  111
500   555
300   7
100   66
`
Then the chart shows 0 values for 200, 400 etc..

Answer (score 3):

After reverse engineering the code created from the graph using the method described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13652972

I found that the option to achieve the same as "Aggregate column a" is

```
.setOption('applyAggregateData',0)
```

It makes zero sense with the 0 and such but considering how badly some of the Gapps Script stuff is, im not surprised.