# “Aggregate Data Series” to average instead of sum in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

###### [Nearly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904069/how-do-i-set-aggregate-data-series-to-average-instead-of-sum-in-google-apps-sc)

---

I am currently trying to create a couple charts through Google App Script. I would like to have one of the series in one of the charts to be aggregated to an average, but I cannot figure out how. The default is `sum` and I have yet to find a way to change it. I have been trying everything I can find to solve this issue. It does not seem to be documented at all in the [chart options](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/chart-configuration-options#column-chart-configuration-options), and I have found minimal documentation elsewhere.

---

#### What I've tried:

[Setting it for each series](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56924340/11861218)

[Reverse engineering the code myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50745042/11861218)

`.setOption('applyAggregateData',0)` (from link above)

`.setOption("series", {"0":{"applyAggregateData":"average"}})` (combination of answers I found)

`.setOption('aggregateFunction',0)` (combination of answers I found)

---

None of this has worked for me, and the best I'm able to get is aggregation by sum. I am not sure what I am missing here, as it seems to have worked for others in the past.

---

**Chart code:**

```js
  var chart2 = exportSheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
  .setPosition(2, 2, 0, 0)
  .addRange(searchSheet.getRange('B11:B'))
  .addRange(searchSheet.getRange('G11:G'))
  .setOption("series", {"0":{"aggregateFunction":"average"}}) //Does not work
  .setOption("title", 'Avg. Ton Per Mile')
  .setOption('hAxis.title', 'Dates')
  .setOption('vAxis.title', 'Salt Usage (T)')
  .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

I also can't seem to make it work but I have thought of a workaround for this. See if it works for you. This can be used until you figure out how to aggregate by average.

#### Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Used only 1 sheet for testing purposes
  var exportSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Set a query formula somewhere that takes the average of your data
  // Our data should now be in Y11:Z that contains the average
  exportSheet.getRange('Y11')
             .setFormula('=query(query({B11:B,G11:G},"select Col1, avg(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), "offset 1", 0)');

  var chart2 = exportSheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
  .setPosition(2, 8, 0, 0)
  // now get the output of the query
  .addRange(exportSheet.getRange('Y11:Y'))
  .addRange(exportSheet.getRange('Z11:Z'))
  .setOption("title", 'Avg. Ton Per Mile')
  .setOption('hAxis.title', 'Dates')
  .setOption('vAxis.title', 'Salt Usage (T)')
  .build();

  exportSheet.insertChart(chart2);
}
```

We pre-process the data via `query`'s average and then pass the range of the output to the chart instead.

#### Sample Data:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Hidden query output:

[image: output2]

#### Note:

- Choose a range that can be hidden from plain sight for your `query` formula if you don't want it to be seen. (Furthermore, you can also actually hide the column to where it will be placed)
- Editing `B11:B` and `G11:G` ranges will still update the chart with aggregation.
- Appending to the range where query is set (in this sample, `Y11:Y` and `Z11:Z`) will not update the average, but just append to the range normally without aggregation.