# Programatically show data labels in Google Spreadsheet Embedded Line Chart

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I managed to generate an embedded line chart via a Google App Script.

Current implementation:

```
var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var myDataRange = mySheet.getRange(1, 1, 10, 5);
var chart = mySheet.newChart();
chart.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE);
chart.addRange(myDataRange);
chart.setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0);

var series = {
  0: {
    color: 'blue',
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {
        fontName: 'Times-Roman',
        fontSize: 18,
        color: '#871b47'
      }
    }
  },
  1: { color: '#a9c5e3' }
};
// styling of series works as long as I display data labels manually
chart.setOption('series', series);
var embeddedChart = chart.build();
mySheet.insertChart(embeddedChart);
```

Now I also want to show data labels in some of the series in the chart.
I was able to style existing data labels that I added manually, but I'm not able to display them in a newly created chart only using Apps Script.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594839/google-apps-script-how-to-set-use-column-a-as-labels-in-chart-embedded-in-spr)
To display data labels for a series I used

```
var series = {
  0: {
    dataLabel: "value"
  }
};
chart.setOption('series', series);
```