# Change Position of Data Label in Embedded Combo Chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, embedded-resource

I´m trying to modify a chart in Google Sheets using Google App Script. I figured out how to do most of the things I need to do, except for one. I need to change the position of the Data Label in the chart. The chart is a Combo Chart that has line and bar charts.

The following code shows the dataLabels, but I can´t find how to change its position(eg. "center","below", etc..).

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];

  chart = chart.modify()
  .setOption('series',{0: {dataLabel: 'value'},1: {dataLabel: 'value',targetAxisIndex: 1}})
  .build();

  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

Apparently there is now documentation on it, but some people found a way to display the dataLabel ([Programatically show data labels in Google Spreadsheet Embedded Line Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003446/programatically-show-data-labels-in-google-spreadsheet-embedded-line-chart)). I was wondering if any one knows how to change the position of the data label.

Comment: What's the type of chart?

Comment: Great point. It is a combo chart using line and bar charts

Comment: Take a similar approach as said in the answer and see what's changed?

Comment: I should start reading the whole answer. =) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

```
var vAxes = [{minValue:0,maxValue:''},{minValue:0,maxValue:''}];
var series = {
  0: {dataLabel: 'value',dataLabelPlacement:"insideBase"},
  1: {dataLabel: 'value',targetAxisIndex: 1,dataLabelPlacement:"center"}
};

chart = chart.modify()
.setOption('vAxes',vAxes)
.setOption('series',series)
.build();
```

I followed the instructions on this answer ([Google Apps Script: How to set "Use column A as labels" in chart embedded in spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594839/google-apps-script-how-to-set-use-column-a-as-labels-in-chart-embedded-in-spr?noredirect=1&lq=1)). Just publish the chart and inspect the code.

here a list of the properties I´ve found:

```
options":{
"treatLabelsAsText":true,
"vAxes":[
{
"minValue":0,
"maxValue":""
},
{
"minValue":0,
"maxValue":""
}
],
"legacyScatterChartLabels":true,
"title":"July/2018, August/2018 and September/2018",
"type":"line",
"lineWidth":2,
"hAxis":{
"useFormatFromData":true,
"title":"Month",
"viewWindow":{
}
},
"series":{
"0":{
"dataLabelPlacement":"insideBase",
"dataLabel":"value",
"annotations":{
"position":"center"
},
"hasAnnotations":true
},
"1":{
"dataLabelPlacement":"below",
"dataLabel":"value",
"annotations":{
"position":"center"
},
"hasAnnotations":true,
"targetAxisIndex":1
}
},
"useFirstColumnAsDomain":true,
"domainAxis":{
"direction":1
},
"width":818,
"booleanRole":"certainty",
"height":506
}
```