# Many Chart options for EmbeddedChartBuilder.setOption() function not available to Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I've created a simple script to create a chart on a sheet, using [`Sheet#newChart`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#newchart)

```
function buildVitalsChart(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Vitals Chart');
  var rg = sh.getRange('A1:E');
  var allChts = sh.getCharts();
  var idA = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < allChts.length; i++){
    sh.removeChart(allChts[i]);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var cht = sh.newChart()
    .asLineChart()
    .addRange(rg)
    .setPosition(2, 6, 0, 0)
    .setOption('title', 'Vitals')
    .build()
  sh.insertChart(cht);
}
```

The chart looks like this:

[image]

However, it's not quite what I want, but I don't know what chart options to set to get what I want. I used the following code to view the current options of the chart:

```
function getVitalsChartOptions() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Vitals Chart');
  var rg = sh.getDataRange();
  var vA = rg.getValues();
  var data = '<br />Data:<br />';
  for (var i = 0; i < vA.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) { data += '<br />'; }
    for (var j = 0; j < vA[i].length; j++) {
      if (j > 0) { data+=', '; }
      data += vA[i][j];
    }
  }
  data += '<br />';
  var opsh = ss.getSheetByName('Options');
  var oprg = opsh.getDataRange();
  var opA = oprg.getValues();
  var cht = sh.getCharts()[0];
  var s = 'Chart Options<br />';
  var optsChecked = '<br />Options Checked but null<br />';
  s += Utilities.formatString('Chart Id=%s<br />Chart Title=%s<br />', cht.getId(), cht.getOptions().get('title'));
  for (var i = 0; i < opA.length; i++) {
    var id = cht.getId();
    var title = cht.getOptions().get('title');
    var opt = opA[i][0].toString();
    try {
      if (cht.getOptions().get(opt) != null) {
        s += Utilities.formatString('%s - Chart Option \'%s\'=<strong>%s</strong><br />', i+1, opA[i][0], cht.getOptions().get(opt));
      } else {
        optsChecked += Utilities.formatString('%s - %s<br />', i+1, opt)
      }
    } catch(e) {
      s += Utilities.formatString('%s option=%s - Error: %s<br />', i+1, opt, e);
      continue;
    }
  }
  s += '<input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  optsChecked += '<input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  data += '<input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s + optsChecked + data).setWidth(800).setHeight(500);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Chart Options');
}
```

And this is the output of that code:

```
Chart Options
Chart Id=u2083708198027
Chart Title=Vitals
2 - Chart Option 'animation.duration'=500
31 - Chart Option 'curveType'=
78 - Chart Option 'height'=371
86 - Chart Option 'lineWidth'=2
95 - Chart Option 'title'=Vitals
141 - Chart Option 'width'=600

Options Checked but null
1 - aggregationTarget
3 - animation.startup
4 - animation.easing
5 - annotations.boxStyle
6 - annotations.datum
7 - annotations.domain
8 - annotations.highContrast
9 - annotations.stem
10 - annotations.style
11 - annotations.textStyle
12 - axisTitlesPosition
13 - backgroundColor
14 - backgroundColor.stroke
15 - backgroundColor.strokeWidth
16 - backgroundColor.fill
17 - chartArea
18 - chartArea.backgroundColor
19 - chartArea.left
20 - chartArea.top
21 - chartArea.width
22 - chartArea.height
23 - colors
24 - crosshair
25 - crosshair.color
26 - crosshair.focused
27 - crosshair.opacity
28 - crosshair.orientation
29 - crosshair.selected
30 - crosshair.trigger
32 - dataOpacity
33 - enableInteractivity
34 - explorer
35 - explorer.actions
36 - explorer.axis
37 - explorer.keepInBounds
38 - explorer.maxZoomIn
39 - explorer.maxZoomOut
40 - explorer.zoomDelta
41 - focusTarget
42 - fontSize
43 - fontName
44 - forceIFrame
45 - hAxis
46 - hAxis.baseline
47 - hAxis.baselineColor
48 - hAxis.direction
49 - hAxis.format
50 - hAxis.gridlines
51 - hAxis.gridlines.color
52 - hAxis.gridlines.count
53 - hAxis.gridlines.units
54 - hAxis.minorGridlines
55 - hAxis.minorGridlines.color
56 - hAxis.minorGridlines.count
57 - hAxis.minorGridlines.units
58 - hAxis.logScale
59 - hAxis.scaleType
60 - hAxis.textPosition
61 - hAxis.textStyle
62 - hAxis.ticks
63 - hAxis.title
64 - hAxis.titleTextStyle
65 - hAxis.allowContainerBoundaryTextCufoff
66 - hAxis.slantedText
67 - hAxis.slantedTextAngle
68 - hAxis.maxAlternation
69 - hAxis.maxTextLines
70 - hAxis.minTextSpacing
71 - hAxis.showTextEvery
72 - hAxis.maxValue
73 - hAxis.minValue
74 - hAxis.viewWindowMode
75 - hAxis.viewWindow
76 - hAxis.viewWindow.max
77 - hAxis.viewWindow.min
79 - interpolateNulls
80 - legend
81 - legend.alignment
82 - legend.maxLines
83 - legend.position
84 - legend.textStyle
85 - lineDashStyle
87 - orientation
88 - pointShape
89 - pointSize
90 - pointsVisible
91 - reverseCategories
92 - selectionMode
93 - series
94 - theme
96 - titlePosition
97 - titleTextStyle
98 - tooltip
99 - tooltip.ignoreBounds
100 - tooltip.isHtml
101 - tooltip.showColorCode
102 - tooltip.textStyle
103 - tooltip.trigger
104 - trendlines
105 - trendlines.n.color
106 - trendlines.n.degree
107 - trendlines.n.labelInLegend
108 - trendlines.n.lineWidth
109 - trendlines.n.opacity
110 - trendlines.n.pointSize
111 - trendlines.n.pointsVisible
112 - trendlines.n.showR2
113 - trendlines.n.type
114 - trendlines.n.visibleInLegend
115 - vAxis
116 - vAxis.baseline
117 - vAxis.baselineColor
118 - vAxis.direction
119 - vAxis.format
120 - vAxis.gridlines
121 - vAxis.gridlines.color
122 - vAxis.gridlines.count
123 - vAxis.gridlines.units
124 - vAxis.minorGridlines
125 - vAxis.minorGridlines.color
126 - vAxis.minorGridlines.count
127 - vAxis.minorGridlines.units
128 - vAxis.logScale
129 - vAxis.scaleType
130 - vAxis.textPosition
131 - vAxis.textStyle
132 - vAxis.ticks
133 - vAxis.title
134 - vAxis.titleTextStyle
135 - vAxis.maxValue
136 - vAxis.minValue
137 - vAxis.viewWindowMode
138 - vAxis.viewWindow
139 - vAxis.viewWindow.max
140 - vAxis.viewWindow.min

Data:
Items, BPHI, BPLO, Pulse, Temperature
1, 127, 67, 46, 97.2
2, 106, 67, 46, 97.2
3, 113, 68, 49, 97.2
4, 110, 70, 51, 97.6
5, 110, 65, 46, 98
6, 115, 68, 48, 97.5
7, 110, 71, 48, 97
8, 111, 68, 51, 97.7
9, 109, 70, 53, 98.1
10, 118, 71, 51, 97.4
11, 116, 74, 51, 97.5
12, 114, 74, 54, 97.7
13, 104, 67, 50, 97.8
14, 108, 70, 51, 97.8
15, 114, 74, 59, 98
16, 109, 74, 57, 97.9
17, 106, 69, 53, 97.4
18, 122, 69, 50, 97.6
19, 110, 69, 55, 97.8
20, 104, 65, 53, 97.4
21, 109, 63, 47, 97.5
22, 110, 69, 46, 97.9
23, 102, 59, 48, 97.7
24, 103, 62, 50, 97.6
25, 106, 66, 51, 97.7
26, 109, 67, 52, 97.6
27, 114, 68, 52, 97.4
28, 112, 70, 59, 97.3
29, 112, 70, 60, 97.9
30, 98, 65, 53, 98.3
31, 104, 65, 53, 97.4
```

So I decided to use the "Edit Chart" functionality on the chart. I want to check the three checkboxes down on the bottom of the edit tool:

[image]

And the chart now looks like this:

[image]

And that's what I want.

I used the above code again to view the options and determine which have changed, so that I can figure out how to do it with Google Apps Script. Here's the pertinent part of that output.

```
Chart Options
Chart Id=u2083711462871
Chart Title=Vitals
2 - Chart Option 'animation.duration'=500
31 - Chart Option 'curveType'=
45 option=hAxis - Error: InternalError: Access to class "(class)" is prohibited.
75 option=hAxis.viewWindow - Error: InternalError: Access to class "(class)" is prohibited.
78 - Chart Option 'height'=371
80 - Chart Option 'legend'=right
86 - Chart Option 'lineWidth'=2
93 option=series - Error: InternalError: Access to class "(class)" is prohibited.
95 - Chart Option 'title'=Vitals
141 - Chart Option 'width'=600
```

**And I conclude that it's not possible to do with Google Apps Script.**

But I'm hoping that perhaps there's something else that I don't know about that can do this.

So the question is:

> **Is there some way to accomplish this with Google Apps Script ?**

Comment: Did you try setting the props as objects, rather than setting each as `'parent.child1'` and `'parent.child2'`? e.g. `'parent', '{"child1": ..., "child2": ...}'` (quote/unquote as needed)

Comment: No.  I didn't try that. I'll  take a look at it and see how it goes. It may take me a while as I'm juggling several balls right now. But thanks for your comment.

Comment: for headers, try --> `.setNumHeaders(1)` -- see [embedded-chart-builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder)

Comment: Perhaps try adding the ranges in two steps, e.g. add A, then add B:E

Comment: I couldn't see that `.setNumHeaders(1)` did anything.  I tried adding the ranges at different times in various combinations but I couldn't get that to work.  Fortunately @|'-'| 's suggestions worked perfectly. `.setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true) //ColAasLabels
  .setOption("applyAggregateData",0) //AggregateColA` .  It's too bad they aren't documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, The correct options were undocumented. By reverse engineering, I was able to find these options.

Try

```
 var cht = sh.newChart()
    .asLineChart()
    .addRange(rg)
    .setPosition(2, 6, 0, 0)
    .setNumHeaders(1) //Use row1 as headers Thank -WhiteHat
    .setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true) //ColAasLabels
    .setOption("applyAggregateData",0) //AggregateColA
    .build();
```

Moreover, The options for chart created from chart editor were widely different from  chart options for the chart created from the apps-script.

Comment: Thank you. That will be very helpful.

Comment: If possible, would you mind speaking a little bit more about how you reverse engineered it.

Comment: Same as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594839/google-apps-script-how-to-set-use-column-a-as-labels-in-chart-embedded-in-spr)

Answer (score 1):

**Using Google Visualization API in a webapp using javascript**

In the end I decided to make a webapp because it's a lot easier to carry my phone around then my laptop.  In addition, my phone allows me to enter data by speaking rather than typing.  I found the charts a lot easier to do in Javascript. Here's the code I've used to create my vitals chart.

Javascript:

```
function drawChart(){
$('#btnA').css('background-color','#ffff00');
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(function(vObj){
console.log(vObj);
var dt=vObj.dA;
var hA=dt[0];
dt.splice(0,1);
var dA=dt.slice();
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
for(var i=0;i<hA.length;i++){
  if(i===0){
    data.addColumn('string',hA[i]);
  }else{
    data.addColumn('number',hA[i]);
  }
}
data.addRows(dA);
var options={
  title:'My Vitals  (Starts: ' + vObj.start + '  -  Ends: ' + vObj.end + ')',
  fontSize: 14,
  fontName: 'Roman',
  width:640,
  height:350,
  pointSize:3,
  hAxis:{slantedText:true,slantedTextAngle:90,textStyle:{color:'#333300',fontName:'Verdana',fontSize:8,bold:true}},
  legend:{position:'top'},
  chartArea:{left:75,top:75,width:'75%',height:'50%'},
  series:{0: {targetAxisIndex: 0}, 1:{targetAxisIndex: 0}, 2:{targetAxisIndex: 0}, 3:{targetAxisIndex: 1}},
  vAxes:[{title:'BP/PULSE',titleTextStyle:{color:'#0000CC',fontName:'Verdana',fontSize:12,bold:true,italic:false},textStyle:{color:'#0000CC',fontName:'Verdana',fontSize:10,bold:true,italic:false}},{title:'TEMP',titleTextStyle:{color:'#007700',fontName:'Verdana',fontSize:12,bold:true,italic:false},textStyle:{color:'#007700',fontName:'Verdana',fontSize:10,bold:true,italic:false}}]
};
var chart=new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('vcht'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'click',function(){emailVitalsDialog()});
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'ready',function(){
  gImgObj['base64Data']=chart.getImageURI().split(',')[1];
  gImgObj.ready=true;
});
chart.draw(data,options);
$('#btnA').css('background-color','#ffffff');
})
.getVitalsData();
}
```

Google Apps Script:

```
function getVitalsData(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(getGlobal('gSSID'));
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Notes');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var vObj={dA:[]};
  var tA=[];
  var dA=[['DATE','BPHI','BPLO','PULSE','TEMP']];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(vA[i][1]=='Vitals'){
      var itemDate=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(vA[i][0]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E");
      var itemData=String(vA[i][2]).trim().split('/');
      itemData.splice(0,0,itemDate);
      var row=itemData.slice();
      dA.push([row[0],Number(row[1]),Number(row[2]),Number(row[3]),Number(row[4])]);
      tA.push(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(vA[i][0]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy"));
    }
  }
  vObj.dA=dA;
  vObj['start']=tA[0];
  vObj['end']=tA[tA.length-1];
  Logger.log(vObj);
  return vObj;
}
```

Here's what the chart looks like:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you run a bit cold

Comment: Yeah.   I noticed that too.  I think it says more about my thermometer than it does about me.