# Generate power series trendline in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, power-series

Something I'm writing in `Google Apps Script` for `Google Sheets` generates a chart. I'd like to have it generate a *power series* trendline, however I cannot figure out how to do this in `Google Apps Script`. I can generate a *polynomial* or *linear* trendline, but I cannot figure out how to have it do it as a *power series*.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart();

chartBuilder.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.SCATTER)
   .addRange(range)
   .setOption("pointSize", 1)
   .setPosition(1, 1, 150, 0)
   .setOption("trendlines", {0: {type: "power series", visibleInLegend: true}});

sheet.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/13652972/

Comment: it's `powerSeries` If you haven't figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to [|'-'|](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/i-i) for finding the answer. Turns out the option is `"powerSeries"` not `"power series"` (man, I feel stupid). Google really ought to make that more clear in their documentation.