# Google Apps Script Chart vAxis.title not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

Something I'm writing in `Google Apps Script` for `Google Sheets` generates a chart. In trying to generate a graph I'd like to set axis titles so I can make the charts more understandable for people other than myself. The problem I'm having is that setting `vAxis.title` in any form doesn't do anything. Once the chart is generated no vertical axis title is made, it's just blank.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart();

chartBuilder.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.SCATTER)
    .addRange(range)
    .setOption("pointSize", 1)
    .setOption("hAxis.title", "X value")
    .setOption("title", "Output")
    .setOption("vAxis.title", "Y output") //Set vertical axis title (not working)
    .setOption("trendlines", {0: {type: "linear", visibleInLegend: true, showR2: true}})
    .setPosition(1, 1, 150, 0);

sheet.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script: How to set "Use column A as labels" in chart embedded in spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594839/google-apps-script-how-to-set-use-column-a-as-labels-in-chart-embedded-in-spr)

Answer (score 3):

This gist solved a very similar issue for me: https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/4125cc280e15c0fc726cb2fe4f35a3f7

Setting `"vAxis"` options through `setOption("vAxis", {title: "y axis"})` seems to be broken. I tried all types of setting but nothing seemed to work.

But as the gist I link to above suggests, all those settings can be set using `setOption("vAxes", {0: {title: "y axis"}})`

So in your code change `.setOption("vAxis.title", "Y output")` to `setOption("vAxes", {0: {title: "Y output"}})`.

You can set multiple options that way, here is a working example from my code: `.setOption("vAxes", {0: {title: "Kilograms", viewWindowMode:'explicit',viewWindow: {max:150,min:50}}})`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can help but I had the same problem, any option related to `vAxis` was not applying (but `hAxis` working correctly). I tried the workaround provided by @TheIceBear, but without success too.

I work with two tab open, one with the sheets and one with the code. As I reloaded the sheets (I was working on `onOpen` event), I noticed the tab with AppsScript did not close (which it always do). I closed it manually and reopen it from sheets menu `Extensions->Apps Script`, and from there the `vAxis` options started to apply, with the default way of setting option vAxis directly.

See example below :

```
  const dateRange = userSheet.getRange('C2:C');
  const differenceRange = userSheet.getRange('F2:F');
  const hAxisOptions = {
    title: 'Period',
    titleTextStyle: {
      bold: true,
    },
  };

  const vAxisOptions = {
    title: 'Difference (h)',
    titleTextStyle: {
      bold: true,
    },
  };

  const chart = userSheet.newChart().asLineChart()
    .addRange(dateRange)
    .addRange(differenceRange)
    .setOption('hAxis', hAxisOptions)
    .setOption('vAxis', vAxisOptions)
    .setOption('height', 400)
    .setOption('width', 800)
    .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
    .setOption('treatLabelsAsText', true)
    .setOption('curveType', 'function')
    .setPosition(1, 7, 0, 0)
    .setOption('title', 'Estimations precision evolution over time')
    .setOption('titleTextStyle', {
      bold: true,
      fontSize: 18,
      color: '#4285f4'
    })
    .build()
  ;

  userSheet.insertChart(chart);
```

Hope it can help someone !