# Setting Y axis options in Google Scripts EmbeddedColumnChartBuilder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I've got a script that copies an existing chart from a Google Sheets dashboard and emails it to a list of users. This is a column chart that uses stacking against both Y axes to display four different series as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2KYd.png).

I've consulted the [Google visualization guide](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#dual-y-charts) but I'm having trouble replicating the axis options in my chart builder, as the code returns a chart with a [single Y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBy1y.png). Code follows:

```
    var charts = sheet.getCharts();
    var builder = charts[1].modify();
    builder.setOption('vAxis.format', '#');
    builder.setOption('vAxis.minValue', 0);
    builder.setOption('height', 500);
    builder.setOption('width', 900);
    builder.setOption('series.2.axis', 'Number');
    builder.setOption('series.3.axis', 'Number');
    builder.setOption('axes.Number.side', 'right');  
    var newchart = builder.build();
    chartBlobs[1] = newchart.getAs('image/png');
```

What are the correct options to incorporate when attempting to assign the right Y axis to multiple series when using the EmbeddedColumnChartBuilder class?

Edit: I've incorporated WhitHat's suggestion below, including a vAxes flag to set axis 1 to the right side and I believe my code is now much closer to the mark; I still receive the same results however.

```js
    var charts = sheet.getCharts();
    var builder = charts[1].modify();
    builder.setOption('vAxis.format', '#');
    builder.setOption('vAxis.minValue', 0);
    builder.setOption('height', 500);
    builder.setOption('width', 900);
    builder.setOption('series.2.targetAxisIndex', 1);
    builder.setOption('series.3.targetAxisIndex', 1);
    builder.setOption('vAxes.1.side', 'right');
    var newchart = builder.build();
    chartBlobs[1] = newchart.getAs('image/png');
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594839