# Usage of some options for embedded chart with Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, charts

Some options of `.setOption` when I create an embedded line chart don't work with me.

[Options for embedded line chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)

For example these:

```js
    .setOption("titlePosition", "in")//accepts Type: string
    .setOption("chartArea.top", 50) //accepts Type: number or string


    //Example: chartArea:{left:20,top:0,width:'50%',height:'75%'} 
    //so I go like:

    var area = {chartArea:{left:20,top:0,width:'50%',height:'75%'}}
    .setOption("chartArea", area)

    //and tried like:

    var area = {left:20,top:0,width:'50%',height:'75%'}
    .setOption("chartArea", area)
```

Nothing works with my embedded line chart.

Here's how I create the chart (it works):

```js
 var chart = sheet.newChart()
        .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
        .addRange(range).setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
        .setPosition(2, 3, 0, 0)
        .setOption("title", name)
        .build();

    sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script: How to set "Use column A as labels" in chart embedded in spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594839/google-apps-script-how-to-set-use-column-a-as-labels-in-chart-embedded-in-spr)

Answer (score 0):

the call to `setOption` is in the wrong place.

the following...

```
var area = {left:20,top:0,width:'50%',height:'75%'}
.setOption("chartArea", area)
```

is the same as...

```
var area = {left:20,top:0,width:'50%',height:'75%'}.setOption("chartArea", area)
```

you're trying use `setOption` on a custom object you've created, `area`,
instead of the chart object.

create `area` first, then add it to the chart...

```
var area = {left:20,top:0,width:'50%',height:'75%'};

var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
    .addRange(range).setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
    .setPosition(2, 3, 0, 0)
    .setOption("title", name)
    .setOption("chartArea", area)  // <-- add area
    .build();
```

Comment: oh sorry I confused you)) my code is like yours, I just wrote the lines together here. Generally I see more examples for chart that uses html but too little explanations of how to use all the methods to the embedded chart.