# How do I set "aggregate data series" to average instead of sum in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-apps, google-apps-script-editor

I'm trying to automate graph generation through google apps script, but the one setting I cannot find anywhere in the documentation is how to change the way the data is aggregated from sum to average in google apps script.

I looked through the documentation and attempted to follow the instructions from [Google Apps Script: How to set "Use column A as labels" in chart embedded in spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594839/google-apps-script-how-to-set-use-column-a-as-labels-in-chart-embedded-in-spr/13652972#13652972), but there didn't seem to be any change in the JSON object.

Comment: For now, I couldn't find any documentation regarding this either. What do you want to do with the json file?

Comment: I don't want to modify the JSON object at all, but the answer I linked seemed to indicate that it could be used to reverse engineer undocumented google apps script options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. It turns out I was looking at the wrong JSON object, and the setting is called "aggregateFunction", which I set to average. However, you can't set it directly using setOption. Instead, you must set it for each series in the chart, for example:

```
.setOption("series", {"0":{"aggregateFunction":"average"}})
```