# Sheet.updateChart resets series color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I have the following chart:

[image]

And a script attached to the button:

```
function updateChart() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(String(chart.getOptions().get('title')));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(String(chart.getOptions().get('series.0.color')));
  sheet.updateChart(chart.modify().build());
}
```

The first time I'm pressing this button it does nothing (as expected). The second time it resets line color to blue.

[image]

`series.0.color` is always null, although `title` is there, so I'm not even sure where to get that color to preserve it in between `.modify()` and `.build()` calls.

How do I prevent `updateChart` from resetting the color?

---

I've tried to inspect options in the published chart as suggested in comments (thanks @TheMaster), unfortunately it still doesn't help with the color issue.

The options are:

```
{
    "hAxis": {
        "title": "x"
    },
    "vAxes": {
        "0": {
            "title": "10x"
        }
    },
    "series": {
        "0": {
            "color": "#008000"
        }
    },
    "useFirstColumnAsDomain": true,
    "width": 600,
    "title": "10x vs \"x\"",
    "height": 371
}
```

And I'm using the following code to get them:

```
function printOption(opts, name) {
  console.log(`${name}: ${opts.get(name)}`)
}

function inspectChart(chart) {
  const options = chart.getOptions();
  printOption(options, 'title');
  printOption(options, 'hAxis.title');
  printOption(options, 'vAxes.0.title');
  printOption(options, 'series.0.color');
}
```

Output is:

```
title: 10x vs "x"
hAxis.title: x
vAxes.0.title: 10x
series.0.color: null
```

As you can see all properties (including nested within array) are there except color

Another interesting point is that once you try to update the color:

```
sheet.updateChart(sheet.getCharts()[0].modify().setOption('series', {0: {color: 'green'}}).build());
```

It applies, but from now you're unable to read that property at all:

```
sheet.getCharts()[0].getOptions().get('series.0.color')
```

The line above fails with `Unexpected error while getting the method or property get on object Charts.ChartOptions.`

Also it looks like no matter what color I choose it is always `#008000` in the published chart, which makes me think I should look for the color somewhere else, but I don't know where

Comment: See the [source and diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594839/google-apps-script-how-to-set-use-column-a-as-labels-in-chart-embedded-in-spr)

Comment: Thank you for the link, but it didn't help. I've updated the post with new details

Comment: Are your sure it's `series.0.color` and not `series.color`? For eg, the [json here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31012304/) shows `color` outside `0`.

Comment: Both of them are `null` when I'm trying to get them from `getOptions().get(...)`. Modifying `series.color` doesn't change the color. Modifying `series.0.color` works, but the option becomes unreadable. The json above is copypasted, so yes, it should be `series.0.color`, although I also saw some docs mentioning that `color` should be within `series`, not `series.0`, but in this case it's unclear how to set different colors for different series

Comment: How about setting `series.0.color` directly instead of a  object? `sheet.updateChart(sheet.getCharts()[0].modify().setOption('series.0.color','green'}}).build());` Also the option becoming unreadable - is it reproducible in a new sheet, new chart after modification?

Comment: I tried it as well, it changes color, but the property still unreadable (throws exception). Yes, it is reproducible in a new sheet, just tried

Comment: Maybe you should create a issue in the issuetracker.  See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for issuetracker.

Comment: Yes, will do, just hoped for a workaround as it may take some time until they fix it