# Enable Total Data Labels via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I'm looking for a way to enable Total Data Labels (screenshot 1) via Google Apps Script. I know how to edit the series themselves, but not entirely sure how to edit the script to make it add Total Labels (screenshot 2).

It's quite frustrating that the documentation available for Google Apps Script doesn't include anything on this. Anyway, more than open to any suggestions at this point.

[Total Data Labels]
[image: 1]
[Total Labels]
[image: 2]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594839/ You may add a answer here after reverse engineering the options.

Comment: @TheMaster how exactly does one do that? I can't seem to figure it out, even though I found that page a few hours ago.

Comment: The answer  provides step by step instructions. Which step are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is meant by "I suggest normalizing the JSON and running diff.". I'm unfortunately not that well versed in the ways of web development, so I'm not even sure where I'm meant to find said JSON.