# How can I retrieve information using `chart.getOptions()`?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I currently have a chart in a google sheet worksheet titled "Present Strength". [Image of chart in the worksheet "Present Strength"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZOSi.png), and I need to verify that it has a title, correct data, as well as x- and y-axis titles using Google App Script.

I want to retrieve information about the chart using Google App Script, specifically the Title, X and Y-Axis Titles, as well as where the data is taken from (the ranges/series of the chart).

I have tried using `chart.GetOptions()`, but whenever I input a string as a parameter in the method it always returns an `Error`:

```
Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.EmbeddedChart.getOptions.
```

The above error was thrown when I typed in `chart.GetOptions('title')`, which should work according to ChatGPT (I have been trying ChatGPT too, but I think it may be outdated because the training data is limited to September 2021).

This is my source code currently:

```js
function Check_Bar_Chart() {
  var charts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Present Strength").getCharts();
  
  if (charts.length == 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Where is your bar chart...?");
    return false;
  } 

  var chart = charts[0];
  Logger.log(chart.getOptions('title'));
}
```

The code recognises that there is a chart, as when the chart is not present, `charts.length == 0` returns `True`. However, I cannot get it to work past that.

This brings me back to my question: how do I retrieve the Title, X and Y-Axis Titles, as well as where the data is taken from (the ranges/series of the chart) using Google App Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your script, I think that the method of getOptions() of Class Chart has no arguments. In this case, it is required to use the method of get(option) of Class ChartOptions.

When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function Check_Bar_Chart() {
  var charts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Present Strength").getCharts();

  if (charts.length == 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Where is your bar chart...?");
    return false;
  }

  var chart = charts[0];
  var options = chart.getOptions();

  Logger.log(options.get('title')); // Chart title
  Logger.log(options.get('hAxis.title')); // X-axis title
  Logger.log(options.get('vAxes.0.title')); // Y-axis title

  var ranges = chart.getRanges().map(r => `'${r.getSheet().getSheetName()}'!${r.getA1Notation()}`);
  Logger.log(ranges);
}
```

- By this modification, the chart title, the X-axis title, and the Y-axis title are retrieved. And also, the source ranges can be also retrieved.
- In this case, `chart.getRanges()` returns the source range objects.

#### References:

- [getOptions() of Class Chart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart#getOptions())
- [get(option) of Class ChartOptions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart-options#getoption)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me :) I have another question though, for get(option) of Class ChartOptions, how do I access the types of values that `option` can take?

Comment: @Lumarstar Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `I have another question though, for get(option) of Class ChartOptions, how do I access the types of values that option can take?`, unfortunately, I think that in the current stage, there is no prepared method for retrieving the list of values of this situation. For example, in my answer, I checked https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart . If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: I understand. I will try things out by reading the documentation further. Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: @Lumarstar Also look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594839/