# Printing dictionaries (JSON) human readable

Tags: python, printing, human-readable

Lets say I have a (nested) dictionary like this (notice the lists-values):

```
dic = {'level1':
            {'level2':(1, 2),
             'level3':
                    [
                     {'level4': (1, 2)},
                     {'level5': (1, 2)}
                    ]
             }
       }
```

I am looking for a proper way to print this dictionary, I am using `json` to do this:

```
import json
print json.dumps(dic, indent=4)
```

and the above code gives me the following output:

```
{
    "level1": {
        "level2": [
            1, 
            2
        ], 
        "level3": [
            {
                "level4": [
                    1, 
                    2
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "level5": [
                    1, 
                    2
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

While the above output is pretty good, it is still hard to read, specially if there are many levels and longer names. 
I have also tried `yaml`

```
import yaml
print yaml.dump(dic)
```

gives the following which looks strange:

```
level1:
  level2: !!python/tuple [1, 2]
  level3:
  - level4: !!python/tuple [1, 2]
  - level5: !!python/tuple [1, 2]
```

Are there any other libraries that can produce better dumps, I think the below output is easier to read:

```
"level1"
    |---"level2":            1, 2
    |---"level3": 
            |---"level4":    1, 2
            |---"level5":    1, 2
```

I believe the above is much easier to read and there may be python libraries out there that can do this.

Comment: The advantage of the default format is that it is valid JSON. I think you would need to roll your own print function to get what you are after.

Comment: You can try [YAML](http://pyyaml.org/), but it's not in the standard library.

Comment: +1 for YAML, it is very readable

Comment: @JasonSperske, see the above for YAML output.

Comment: @PavelAnossov, see the above for YAML output

Comment: Top solution is in python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-to-pretty-print-json-from-the-command-line

Comment: Could it look that way because you have () around your list if units and not []?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is adapted from a activestate code example. Can't say its pretty, but may get you headed in the right direction:

```
myDict = {'level1':
         {'level2':(1, 2),
          'level3':
                [
                 {'level4': (1, 2)},
                 {'level5': (1, 2)},
                ], 
         'level6': [1,2,3], 
         'level7':{'level8': (1,2), 'level9': (1,2)}
         }
    }



def prettyPrint(dictionary, ident = '', braces=1):
    for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print '%s%s%s%s' % (ident, braces*'[', key, braces*']') 
            prettyPrint(value, ident+'  ', braces+1)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            ndict=0
            for v in value:
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    ndict += 1
            if ndict:
                print '%s%s' % (ident, key) 
                for e in value:
                    if isinstance(e, dict):
                        prettyPrint(e, ident+'  ', braces+1)
                    else: 
                         print ident+'%s : %s' %(key, e)
            else:
                print ident+'%s : %s' %(key, value)
        else:
            print ident+'%s : %s' %(key, value)

prettyPrint(myDict)


[level1]
  level2 : (1, 2)
  level3
    level4 : (1, 2)
    level5 : (1, 2)
  level6 : [1, 2, 3]
  [[level7]]
    level8 : (1, 2)
    level9 : (1, 2)
```