# Pretty print complex JSON input

Tags: python, json, command-line, pretty-print

I have gone through 
[How can I pretty-print JSON in (unix) shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json/352160#352160)
and other Stackoverflow posts on "pretty print JSON" but they are only good for simple inputs
like,

```bash
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | python -m json.tool
```

When I try to do something like this

```bash
echo '{"group" : {list : [1,2,3]}, "list" : ["a","b","c"]}' | python -m json.tool
```

it fails.

Gives me the error

```bash
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 13 (char 12)
```

**PS:** Why am I trying to pass a complex json input? I'm trying to solve question 1 from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/browserstack-placement-paper/)

---

**Edit:** Thanks for prompt reply. But what if I'm looking for an output like this 
{
"group" : {
"list" : [1,2,3]
},
"list" : ["a","b","c"]
}

Comment: You may want to let that site know their sample is invalid.

Comment: Will do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON input is invalid; you need to quote the first `list` key:

```bash
echo '{"group" : {"list" : [1,2,3]}, "list" : ["a","b","c"]}' | python -m json.tool
#                 ^^^^^^
```

The tool can handle *any complexity* of JSON, provided you give it *valid* JSON input. With the error corrected, Python outputs:

```
$ echo '{"group" : {"list" : [1,2,3]}, "list" : ["a","b","c"]}' | python -m json.tool
{
    "group": {
        "list": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    },
    "list": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
"group" : {list : [1,2,3]}
```

you have invalid json. it is expecting `list` to be a string, which is not. Hence the error. Changing:

```
"group" : {"list" : [1,2,3]}
```

will solve the issue.