# How can I get accurately get a value from some json using just curl and python

Tags: python, json, shell, curl, command-line-interface

I need to accurately grab a single value out of a JSON data structure Curl'd from an api using the tools that are natively available on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance (Python and CURL) are there by default so I don't have fly anything in via yum/github/curl.  The value in question is going to be used for an Amazon User data script to uniquely identify servers in a cluster so compactness is important.

eg:

```
curl https://superdooperapi.io/get-me-an-id
```

Will return

```
{ "id": 12398990, "date": "2015-01-10" }
```

I just need the single numeric value for `id` so I can use it in a shell script.  I could use grep/sed/awk but that just seems messy.
It's easy to do writing a full python script to execute, but I'd like an elegant single line solution that I can use in a startup script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pretty-print JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some simple compact python that will do it for you:

```py
curl -s https://superdooperapi.io/get-me-an-id | python -c 'import json,sys;data=json.load(sys.stdin);print data["id"]'
```

that will return `12398990`

Comment: Also see this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7961562/341156