# clang-format a json file

Tags: javascript, json, clang-format

I have a json file. If I run clang-format on it, it formats it as though it's code (ugly).

```
{
  "name" : "My great app",
           "description" : "It's really cool.",
                           "version" : "0.0.1"
}
```

If I put 'foo = ' at the start of the file, it's great, but it's not json anymore.

```
foo = {
  "name" : "My great app",
  "description" : "It's really cool.",
  "version" : "0.0.1"
}
```

How can I get clang-format to format the bare object in the json file as in the second example?

Comment: you could prefix the file with `foo =`, run clang-format and then remove the prefix.

Comment: JSON is a format, not a data type of something. U can use native objects and then stringify them to json.

Comment: Here's some other options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-in-unix-shell-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd do it using python, using the `json`'s package pretty printer:

```
cat mydata.json | python -mjson.tool
```

and if you don't like the defaults:

```
cat mydata.json | python -c 'import json, sys; print(json.dumps(json.load(sys.stdin), indent=4, sort_keys=True))'
```

Otherwise, I don't have `clang-format` installed, and for the sake of pretty printing, I'd rather use an existing tool.

N.B.: You can also do it within `vim` and use the `==` normal command on the full file selection ☺

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on getting this accepted, https://reviews.llvm.org/D93528, this does what you suggest by adding a hidden "x = " at the front of the file, then remove that after formatting using the replacement mechanism.

Until this gets landed I think you could do something similar perhaps with clang-apply-replacements

Comment: Do you have (or know about others) any plans to improve support for JSON formatting via clang-format? I've just tried it in LLVM 13, it seems that only `IndentWidth` option is supported.

Comment: What else wold you want?

Comment: In particular spaces around `:`

Answer (score 2):

Another program that I like to use is [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). It's pretty easy to use, and the documentation is great. For example, for simple reformatting you can do this:

```
jq . test.json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `json_pp` on your system you can also do:

```
cat test.json | json_pp
```