# Saving dict as JSON so that they are human readable

Tags: python, json, human-readable

When a dict is saved using json.dump, it is only a single-line. I want to make this a human-readable format such as this website does - https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

How can I do this in python? I tried to capture `pprint` output, but it is an invalid string to store JSON in.

Specifically, is there an acceptable default way to do this in python  directly?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-python-prettyprint-a-json-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json

Comment: I use: `json.dump(args_data, argsfile, indent=4)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should utilize the `indent` and `separators` parameters in the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). From the docs there:

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True,
...                  indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

Comment: why is your value ident 4 and not some other value?

Comment: @CharlieParker It's a common value (indent 4 spaces). You can set it to something else, if you want.

Comment: why do you need `separators=(',', ': ')`?

Comment: I ended up using: `json.dump(args_data, argsfile, indent=4)`