# Combine several files, with a separator, into one file

Tags: json, linux, shell, cat

I have several (~300,000) files of individual JSON objects that I want to combine into a single file that is a JSON array.  How can I do this on linux assuming they are all in the location "~/data_files"?

**FileA**

```
{
  name: "Test",
  age: 23
}
```

**FileB**

```
{
  name: "Foo",
  age: 5
}
```

**FileC**

```
{
  name: "Bar",
  age: 5
}
```

**Example Output: (begins and ends with brackets, and added commas between objects)**

```
[
    {
      name: "Test",
      age: 23
    },
    {
      name: "Foo",
      age: 5
    },
    {
      name: "Bar",
      age: 5
    }
]
```

**What I've tried:**

I know I can use `cat` to combine a bunch of files, not sure how to do it for all files in a directory yet, but trying to figure that out.  Also trying to figure out how to have the `,` between files I'm concatenating, haven't seen a command for it yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you seem a little new to unix I'll try to give you a solution that is simple and doesn't introduce too many new concepts. I'll leave clever and novel to the other posters. This solution will be *very* efficient since all I'm doing is streaming files into files.

To start with we will create a new file in our home directory with a square bracket in it.
`echo "[" > ~/tmp.json`

Now we loop through all the files in your data_files directory
and append them to our new file. The `>>` will add them to whats already there. If you used a `>` then the file would get overwritten each time.
The `echo` will add a comma when the `cat` has finished outputting the file.

`for i in ~/data_files/*; do cat $i;echo ","; done >> ~/tmp.json`

So now we have your 300k files in one file called tmp.json, with each entry seperated by a comma, but the last line of the file is also a comma and that is not what we want.
 The `sed` command below behaves like `cat` except that `'$d'` tells it to omit the last line of the file.
 So we create a new file with all but the last line of our temporary file.
`sed '$d' ~/tmp.json > ~/finished.json`

We need to close our square bracket
`echo "]" >> ~/finished.json`

And finally we delete our temporary file
`rm ~/tmp.json`

And we are done.

```
[
{
    name: "Test",
    age: 23
}
,
{
    name: "Foo",
    age: 5
}
,
{
    name: "Bar",
    age: 5
}
]
```

A quick glance at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json) post about pretty printing json will point you at a command line tool that will take your finished.json file and turn it into *exactly* the output you asked for.

Comment: Hi @niall-cosgrove, I tried running my adapted version of this line `for i in ~/data_files/*; do cat $i;echo ","; done >> ~/tmp.json` and it just ends up creating an infinite loop with a never ending file. Here's my adapted version:
`for f in *.txt; do cat $f;echo ","; done >> masterDoc.txt`
Any ideas why this is looping?

Comment: @GPP looks like `masterDoc.txt` is in the same directory as all your other text files so I think when the for loop gets that far you are appending its contents to itself forever.  If you call it anything that doesn't end in `.txt` you should be fine.  f.e. `for f in *.txt; do cat $f;echo ","; done >> masterDoc`  That way `f` is never matched with your output file.

Comment: thanks @NiallCosgrove just confirming that your answer was the solution to the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

a simple for loop and couple of sed will do

```
$ echo "[" > all; 
  for f in file{A,B,C}; 
  do 
     sed 's/^/\t/;$s/$/,/' "$f" >> all; 
  done; 
  sed -i '$s/,/\n]/' all

$ cat all
[
 {
   name: "Test",
   age: 23
 },
 {
   name: "Foo",
   age: 5
 },
 {
   name: "Bar",
   age: 5
 }
]
```

or the same to stdout

```
$ echo "["; for f in file{A,B,C}; do sed 's/^/\t/;$s/$/,/' "$f"; done |
sed `'$s/,/\n]/'`
```

to run for all files in the directory change `file{A,B,C}` to `*`

Answer (score 1):

This script should work even if the number of files is 300K+. Also this script is faster than `sed` solution since input files are not modified.

```
#!/bin/sh
tmp="/dev/shm/${USER}.find.tmp"
out='all.json'
find . -maxdepth 1 -name file\* > ${tmp}
echo '[' > ${out}
for f in $(head -n -1 ${tmp})
do
  cat ${f} >> ${out}
  echo ',' >> ${out}
done
f=$(tail -n 1 ${tmp})
cat ${f} >> ${out}
echo ']' >> ${out}
rm -f -- ${tmp}
```

Comment: a minor point but possibly relevant - negative arguments to head won't work in all unix systems. That option is specific to GNU implementations.

Comment: You can use `sed '$d' "${tmp}"` to list all lines in `${tmp}` except the last (as an alternative to `head -n -1`).

Comment: @user6170930 OP was about Linux, so I assumed GNU tools are available.

Comment: quite right. just mentioned it for others who land here via search

Answer (score 1):

And python version for completeness:

```
import os, sys

dir = sys.argv[1]

print "["
for fn in os.listdir(dir):
    with open(dir + '/'  + fn, 'r') as f:
        read_data = f.read()
        print read_data,
    print ","
print "]"
```

Answer (score 0):

jc.. use `jq`, it is or should be best practice at the point

```sh
$ cat <<eof | jq -s
> { "key": 1 }
> { "key2": 2 }
> { "key3": 3 }
> eof
[
  {
    "key": 1
  },
  {
    "key2": 2
  },
  {
    "key3": 3
  }
]
```

If your reqs are to JUST push json objects into queue, any other suggestion is naive at best, which is not a statement based on opinion.