# convert long line of json file to readable file

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, jq

I need help about how to convert long line of json file to readable file

this is the json format

```
"version": 1, "partitions": [{"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 7, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [3, 0, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 4, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [3, 0, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 15, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [2, 3, 0]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 9, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [2, 3, 0]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 12, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [2, 3, 0]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 1, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [3, 2, 0]}, {"topic": "CatchAllTopic", "partition": 0, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 3, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 17, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 3, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 6, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [2, 0, 3]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 3, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [2, 0, 3]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 14, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 2, 3]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 0, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [2, 0, 3]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 11, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 2, 3]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 16, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [3, 0, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 8, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 3, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 2, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 3, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 13, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [3, 0, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 5, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 3, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 10, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [3, 0, 2]}]}
```

or actually more like this:

[image]

while we want the file as the following format

more file.json

```
{"partitions":
       [{"topic": "foo",
         "partition": 1,
          "replicas": [1,2,3],
          "log_dirs": ["any","any","any"]
       }],
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Maybe `jq . file.json`?

Comment: Unless you can provide more context, @dibery's suggestion sounds about right.

Comment: see the update in my question

Comment: so after we covert it to readable , then how to convert it back as previews ?

Comment: @Judy Use the `--compact-output` option to `jq` to make it print output on one line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pretty-print JSON in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: Neither of the sample inputs is valid JSON, and since both include a trailing `}`, it would appear the initial `{` is also missing.  Please clarify -- is the question in essence about valid JSON or about fixing up mangled data to make it valid JSON, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty print a json string using Python 3 if you cant install jq for some reason :

```
echo '{ "name" : "Matias", "age": 32 }' | python3 -c 'import sys
import json
print(json.dumps(json.load(sys.stdin), indent="  "))
'
```

This will print :

```
{
  "name": "Matias",
  "age": 32
}
```

Hope it's useful.