# How can I minify JSON in a shell script?

Tags: json, unix, command-line, minify

I've been looking for a way to uglify some JSON while in my bash console. This help using it afterward in another command (for example, to pass json inline to `httpie`)

Giving:

```
{
    "foo": "lorem",
    "bar": "ipsum"
}
```

I want to obtain:

```
{"foo":"lorem","bar":"ipsum"}
```

<sub>**NOTE:** this question is intentionnaly greatly inspired by [it's pretty-print counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/352098/6320039). However, googling for *bash minify json* didn't give me a proper result, hence this questions for the minify/uglify.</sub>

Comment: suggestion: add some white-space to the sample strings here.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are meaning @orionelenzil, but i you mean strings with spaces inside (`"   lorem.  "`), I'm not expecting those to be compacted afterward. This question is just an example btw, you'll see that the answer also use an external, way larger json

Comment: right, it's a minor thing but with your existing example naively removing whitespace would work fine, but if there were whitespace in the values or keys then such a simple approach would not work, thus motivating the use of something fancier like the suggestions in the answers.

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to get what you want... I'd rather keep it simple anyway, this is not a use case, just an example!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## TL;DR

**no install**

```bash
python -c 'import json, sys;json.dump(json.load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout)' < my.json
```

**very fast** (with [jj](https://github.com/tidwall/jj))

```bash
jj -u < my.json
```

## Perf benchmark

Here's the script, using [`hyperfine`](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp json.XXX)
tmp_md=$(mktemp md.XXX)

trap "rm $tmp $tmp_md" EXIT

cat <<JSON > $tmp
{
    "foo": "lorem",
    "bar": "ipsum"
}
JSON
hyperfine \
    --export-markdown $tmp_md \
    --warmup 100 \
    "jj -u < $tmp" \
    "yq eval -j -I=0 < $tmp" \
    "xidel -s - -e '\$json' --printed-json-format=compact < $tmp" \
    "jq --compact-output < $tmp" \
    "python3 -c 'import json, sys;json.dump(json.load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout)' < $tmp" \
    "ruby -r json -e 'j JSON.parse \$stdin.read' < $tmp"

pbcopy < $tmp_md
```

The result on my mac — MacBook Air (M1, 2020), 8 GB:

| Command | Mean [ms] | Min [ms] | Max [ms] | Relative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `jj -u < json.p72` | 1.3 ± 0.2 | 0.9 | 2.7 | 1.00 |
| `yq eval -j -I=0 < json.p72` | 4.4 ± 0.4 | 3.8 | 7.8 | 3.37 ± 0.65 |
| `xidel -s - -e '$json' --printed-json-format=compact < json.p72` | 5.5 ± 0.3 | 5.0 | 6.5 | 4.19 ± 0.77 |
| `python3 -c 'import json, sys;json.dump(json.load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout)' < json.p72` | 14.0 ± 0.4 | 13.4 | 15.0 | 10.71 ± 1.89 |
| `jq --compact-output < json.p72` | 14.4 ± 2.0 | 13.2 | 33.6 | 11.02 ± 2.45 |
| `ruby -r json -e 'j JSON.parse $stdin.read' < json.p72` | 47.3 ± 0.6 | 46.1 | 48.5 | 36.10 ± 6.32 |

Result for a large JSON file (14k lines):

```bash
http https://france-geojson.gregoiredavid.fr/repo/regions.geojson | jj -p > $tmp
```

| Command | Mean [ms] | Min [ms] | Max [ms] | Relative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `jj -u < json.wFY` | 3.4 ± 0.7 | 2.7 | 12.2 | 1.00 |
| `jq --compact-output < json.wFY` | 35.1 ± 0.4 | 34.5 | 36.1 | 10.24 ± 2.23 |
| `python3 -c 'import json, sys;json.dump(json.load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout)' < json.wFY` | 47.4 ± 0.5 | 46.3 | 48.7 | 13.82 ± 3.01 |
| `xidel -s - -e '$json' --printed-json-format=compact < json.wFY` | 55.5 ± 1.2 | 54.7 | 63.5 | 16.17 ± 3.53 |
| `ruby -r json -e 'j JSON.parse $stdin.read' < json.wFY` | 94.9 ± 0.7 | 93.8 | 96.8 | 27.65 ± 6.02 |
| `yq eval -j -I=0 < json.wFY` | 3087.0 ± 26.6 | 3049.3 | 3126.8 | 899.63 ± 195.81 |

<sub>And [here is the pretty print](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61119751/6320039) counterpart benchmark</sub>

Comment: How about `uglify-js`?

Comment: If you are talking about this: http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/, it is a javascript uglifier, not JSON. And node is less often available than python on computers. Hence I'm not sure it is a good candidate :/

Comment: Example for the python line: `python -c 'import json, sys;json.dump(json.load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout)' < myfile.json`

Comment: Ah, very nice. Thank you for testing `xidel`.

Comment: @UlysseBN Could you include/update results for `xidel`'s latest [development build](https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/Xidel%20development/)? Lots of improvements. Maybe you can also include `xidel` in your [pretty print post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61119751/6320039)?

Comment: @Reino I've updated the script for a clearer one, however the latest `xidel` version on brew is only `0.9.8`.

Comment: I have no idea what all these numbers (and i/s for instance) mean, so clearer... not for me. That's a real pitty. v0.9.8 is really old. The recommended binaries to use are those from the development branch.

Comment: @Reino feel free to [contribute to Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#contributing) to add this build! The `i/s` means iterations per seconds, so how many times the script runs in one second. `i/100ms` is the same on a 100ms scale rather than 1s

Comment: `jj` is great, also doesn't throw an error with deeply nested trees. `jq` has a recursion limit of 512.

Comment: the 'no install' python command-line here produces not-fully-compacted JSON for me. it has spaces after `:` and `,`'s.  `jq -c` omits those spaces.

Comment: acurate eye @orionelenzil! I saw it as well, but I don't believe the difference is great enough to make a significant difference in file size. In that case, better using other format than JSON such as [msgpack](https://msgpack.org/)

Answer (score 56):

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) `-c` (compact) option.

`jq -c . < input.json`

Comment: Doesn't work if you have a deeply nested JSON file. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75524357/how-to-increase-depth-limit-of-jq

Comment: In fact, the recursion limit of `jq` seems to be 512, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75524782/7483211 and based on benchmarks `jj` is much faster!

Comment: ```cat input.json | jq -c > output.json```
is less awkward and more handy for huge files

Answer (score 1):

`yq` worked for me, via utilization of input file (containing the prettified JSON)
`yq eval -j -I=0 uglify-test.txt`
Docs link: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/convert

Comment: I've added it to the benchmark! It seems surprisingly faster than jq !

Answer (score 0):

With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel -s input.json -e '$json' --printed-json-format=compact
#or
xidel -s input.json -e 'serialize-json($json)'
{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}
```

Interesting "benchmark", Ulysse BN.
I couldn't test `jj`, but on my old cpu these are my results:

```
var='{
    "foo": "lorem",
    "bar": "ipsum"
}'

time (for i in {1..100}; do python -c 'import json, sys;json.dump(json.load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout)' <<< "$var" >& /dev/null; done)

real    0m10.813s
user    0m7.532s
sys     0m5.798s

time (for i in {1..100}; do jq --compact-output <<< "$var" >& /dev/null; done)

real    0m10.500s
user    0m1.835s
sys     0m0.769s

time (for i in {1..100}; do xidel -se '$json' --printed-json-format=compact <<< "$var" >& /dev/null; done)

real    0m2.250s
user    0m1.692s
sys     0m0.889s
```

Comment: Very interesting solution! I've added it to my benchmark to have an answer easier to read :)

Answer (score 0):

## jq-minify

Here is a bash script that will write back to the file minified

> works with bash v3.2+ and jq v1.6+

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
path=
options=()
# change -c to -r to get pretty-print
set -- "$@" -c .
for arg; do
  if [ -f "$arg" ]; then
    if [ -n "$path" ]; then
      echo "Cannot specify multiple paths to jq-minify" >&2
      exit 1
    fi
    path="$arg"
  else
    options+=("$arg")
  fi
done
tmp=$(mktemp)
jq "${options[@]}" "$path" >"$tmp"
cat "$tmp" >"$path"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see this scripts point, why not `jq -c file > file1` ?