# extract single json data from file containing multiple json data and make it compact

Tags: json, bash

For example, the file looks like this:

```
{
  "a":1
}
{
  "b":2
}
```

I want turn it into :

```
{"a":1}
{"b":2}
```

How can I do that in bash ?

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: yes, But I've explained my intention.

Comment: If you provide valid sample JSON data it's a lot easier to test answers.

Comment: Please provide actual, valid sample data (*yes, but I've explained my intention* does not work) and your attempts to solve the problem yourself. SO is not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem first. Once you've done that and run into difficulties, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your code in the form of a [mre], and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help.

Comment: Sorry for that. I forgot to add quotes

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125013/how-can-i-minify-json-in-a-shell-script/61125014.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial with `jq`:

```sh
$ jq -c . input.json
{"a":1}
{"b":2}
```

The `-c` option stands for *compact* output, with each value on a single line.

Comment: Wow, I used jq, but haven't known it can deal with multiple `{ }` pairs.

Comment: @LewisChan Yup, your file has two JSON objects in it. `jq` will process one at a time until until the entire file's been read (Unlike a lot of tools that expect a file to only contain one JSON value)