# How to increase depth limit of jq?

Tags: json, jq, minify

When trying to minify a deeply nested JSON file (~10k deep) using `jq` I got a parse error:

```
$ jq -c . <input.json >minified.json
parse error: Exceeds depth limit for parsing at line 227263, column 355
```

How can I increase the depth limit? Is there a command line option? I couldn't find anything about this in the man page.

Comment: If you're just using `jq -c` to convert to compact form, rather than doing anything fancier, I'd think about switching to an alternate implementation; there's a native-Go alternative at https://github.com/itchyny/gojq f/e, or `python -mjson.tool --compact` may suffice. Could still potentially hit a max stack depth on either of those, but I'd start by testing.

Comment: There's now a feature request issue for increasing depth from 256 where you can add your support: https://github.com/jqlang/jq/issues/2846

Answer (score 3):

Workaround is to use another tool, e.g. [`jj`](https://github.com/tidwall/jj), which does the job perfectly, and probably also faster in general, even if `jq` doesn't error.

```bash
jj -u <input.json >minified.json
```

Binaries available at: https://github.com/tidwall/jj/releases/latest or via homebrew:

```bash
brew install tidwall/jj/jj
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the C implementation, you'd have to remake the binary after changing MAX_PARSING_DEPTH in jv_parse.c, in which the relevant line is currently:

```
#define MAX_PARSING_DEPTH (256)
```

As best I can tell, there does not seem to be any downside to increasing the limit to a very large number.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the source code! Would be nice if this was surfaced as a CLI option.

Answer (score 1):

gojq (the Go implementation of jq) has a limit on the maximum depth it can handle: it's greater than 1,024 but less than 10,000.

I've verified that [jj](/questions/tagged/jj) and my "JSON Machine"-based utility, [jm](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jm), can both handle a depth of 10,000. The following are equivalent ways of compactifying a JSON document, at least if the limit isn't breached:

```
   jj -u @this < input.json
   jm input.json
```